# vba: This key is already associated with an element of this collection

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim arr As New Collection, a
Dim aFirstArray() As Variant    

...some code

For Each a In aFirstArray
   arr.Add a, a
Next
```

i get this error: `This key is already associated with an element of this collection`

on this line :  `arr.Add a, a`

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more code?

from this what you have all I can tell you is that what your error says. The `a` is already in the collection (**the key is supposed to be an unique string**). BTW. is the `a` a string?

Or maybe you have some repetition in your array which would try to add 1+ time the same item?

Comment: mike im using this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array/3017973#3017973 to get unique values from the array

Comment: You missing out `On Error Resume Next` which omits your error and keeps going, thus your unique values.