# Loading an array with only unique values

Tags: vba

I have a range I am looping through in VBA:

```
For Lrow = Firstrow To Lastrow Step 1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "E")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then

            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow
```

Within that if statement I need to load an array with each value only once

MB-NMB-ILA
MB-NMB-ILA
MB-NMB-STP
MB-NMB-STP
MB-NMB-WAS
MB-NMB-WAS
MB-NMB-WAS

So for the array I only want MB-NMB-ILA, MB-NMB-STP, and MB-NMB-WAS

Can anyone help me out, my brain isn't working right on a Monday! Thanks

Comment: You can use a dictionary to take unique values and then copy them back into your array (or use directly the dictionary, the way you prefer). Notice this question is already answered [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array). Rgds

Answer (score 1):

You could use filter to test if something exists in the array.

```
Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("test1", "test2", "test3")
If UBound(Filter(arr, "blah")) > -1 Then
    Debug.Print "it is in the array"
Else
    Debug.Print "it's not in the array"
End If
```

You could also use a collection and write a sub to add only unique items to the collection

```
Dim col As New Collection
Sub addIfUnique(sAdd As String)
    Dim bAdd As Boolean: bAdd = True
    If col.Count > 0 Then
        Dim iCol As Integer
        For iCol = 1 To col.Count
            If LCase(col(iCol)) = LCase(sAdd) Then
                bAdd = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next iCol
    End If
    If bAdd Then col.Add sAdd
End Sub
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    For a = 1 To 10
        addIfUnique "item " & a
        For b = 1 To 10
            addIfUnique "item " & b
        Next b
    Next a
    For a = 1 To col.Count
        Debug.Print col(a)
    Next a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have the following in cell A1 to A5 and want an array of unique values i.e. {a,b,c,d}

```
        A
1      "a"
2      "b"
3      "c"
4      "c"
5      "d"
```

The follow two pieces of code will help achieve this:

**CreateUniqueArray** - get val from each cell and add to array if not already in array

**IsInArray** - utility function to check if value in array by performing simple loop

I have to say that this is the brute force way and would welcome any improvements...

```
Sub Test()
    Dim firstRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer, cnt As Integer, iCell As Integer
    Dim myArray()
    cnt = 0
    firstRow = 1
    lastRow = 10

    For iCell = firstRow To lastRow
        If Not IsInArray(myArray, Cells(iCell, 1)) Then
            ReDim Preserve myArray(cnt)
            myArray(cnt) = Cells(iCell, 1)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next iCell
End Sub

Function IsInArray(myArray As Variant, val As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer, found As Boolean
    found = False

    If Not Len(Join(myArray)) > 0 Then
        found = False
    Else
        For i = 0 To UBound(myArray)
            If myArray(i) = val Then
               found = True
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    IsInArray = found
End Function
```