# Excel 2016: Error accessing file. Network connection may have been lost

Tags: excel, vba

we are developing an Excel 2016 Workbook using VBA. I descrivbe the error from my side, but it occurs at several independent Computers - even at the customer's where the Worksheet used to work fine...

I have a Worksheet containing some cells and a Button which is bound to a VBA macro.

Now, when I change tge size, the position or the text of the button or when I change the macro's name I get the error

> "Excel 2016: Error accessing file. Network connection may have been
>   lost"

No network connection is used in that place and the file is stored locally.

Giving goolge some tries I found many posts concerning Project 2000 and PowerPoint 2000, but not for Excel of any versions. (The given causes are that a Project or PP master has been corrupted)

When I save my Workbook, open it on another computer with Excel 2010, save it there all seemed to be fixed. Several hours of work and several file saves later I get the same error.

Does anyone know this error in Excel 2016? Can I deliver more content so you can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just came across this error, using the option to "Open and Repair" from the drop-down on the button on Excel's "Open" dialog fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Open and Repair" as suggested in the answer from `mike spurr` may
   work in some instances so its worth trying.  However, sometimes it serves as only a temporary fix and soon the error recurs.
2. Frequently the issue stems from incorrectly implementing, *ahem*,
   the `IMPLEMENTS` statement.  So if your source code has classes with
   the `IMPLEMENTS` statement check these solutions also:

   [Error accessing file. Network connection may have been
   lost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60439740/8958130)

   [IMPLEMENTS circular dependency
   issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60440654/8958130)

Answer (score 0):

Rename the end of the file for example rotadocs - call this rotadocs.old and save it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31625428)