# Excel VBA: Why "Sheets" collection is not a "Collection"?

Tags: excel, vba, inheritance, collections, polymorphism

A simple question on Excel VBA: If "Sheets" object is a collection, why the following sentence returns false? (entered at the Inmediate panel)

```
debug.print TypeOf Sheets Is Collection
Falso
```

I have discovered it because I made a function that takes a Collection as parameter. The function works with variables that I have declared as Collection, but doesn't work with other collections (such as Sheets collection).

Perhaps VBA is failing in inheritance and/or polymorphism?

---

**Edit**: As JosieP and mehow have explained, the Sheets collection doesn't inherits from the Collection class/interface, so it is not a Collection, and can't be used polymorphically as a Collection.

So now the question is: Why Sheets isn't a subclass of Collection? Why they haven't inherited from Collection? It should be a piece of cake, given the methods/properties already implemented into Sheets. As I can see, the Collection class/interface only requires 4 methods:

```
Add
Count
Item
Remove
```

And Sheets already implements 4 similar methods/properties:

```
Add
Count
Item
Delete
```

So the mapping would be trivial. They could have converted Sheets collection into a Collection easily.

---

**Edit 2**: I thank mehow for the suggestion on asking MS, but I won't do it, since they will probably say "it is not a design bug, it is a feature" :). More food for thinking: Run the following code in a new workbook:

```
Sheets.Add.name = "sh2"
Sheets.Add.name = "sh3"

Dim col As Collection
Set col = New Collection
col.Add Sheets(1)
col.Add Sheets(2)
col.Add Sheets(3)

For Each ele In col
    Debug.Print "ele in col:  " & ele.name
Next ele

For Each ele In Sheets
    Debug.Print "ele in Sheets:  " & ele.name
Next ele
```

It is strange to me that both "col" and "Sheets" can be iterated the same way, with a "for each" loop, but they don't share a common interface. If I had to design the classes, the hierarchy would be:

```
    iIterable       (interface)
        |
        |
    iCollection     (interface)
       / \
      /   \
     /     \
Collection  cSheets    (classes)
```

and Sheets would be an object (instance) of cSheets class.

In this way, the function I made (that currently takes a Collection parameter), would take a iCollection parameter, so it could work both with a Collection instance and with Sheets.

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you expect to "why?". the Sheets class does not inherit from the VBA Collection nor does it implement a Collection interface (there is no Remove method for example)

Comment: your question is now only answerable by whichever programming team was responsible ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Sheets` is a collection of `Object` type and not an object of `Collection` type.

Like JosieP said

> the Sheets class does not inherit from the VBA Collection nor does it
> implement a Collection interface (there is no Remove method for
> example)

should be enough to understand.

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174306(v=office.11).aspx)

[image]

```
Sub Main()

    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    
    Debug.Print VarType(c), TypeOf c Is Collection

    Debug.Print VarType(Sheets), TypeOf Sheets Is Object
    
End Sub
```

To confirm open the `Object Browser` with <kbd>F2</kbd> and type find `Sheets`

---

Address your second question to Microsoft. But bear in mind that `Collection` can be empty while the `Sheets` always needs to have at least one Sheets or Chart object.

Lots of *things* depend on the Sheets collection object in Excel that's why I think it had to be a separate class. I can't see nothing wrong by Implementing ICollection interface and providing a separate implementation but like I said ask Microsoft (good question).

---

The `for each` loop is possible because each VBA class has [attributes](http://web.archive.org/web/20110218043811/https://www.networkautomation.com/automate/urc/resources/livedocs/bpa/7/Technical_Reference/Basic_Scripting/Definitions/Sbe6_000Attribute_DefinintionStatement.htm). Not all attributes are visible via the IDE but they do exist (more of VB6 general knowledge than just reference to VBA).

Ok, now to answer your third question. You can iterate over a collection because it implements IUnknown interface `NewEnum()` (*enumarable method*). You specify the default iterating object over a collection of your type (in Sheets case its Sheets collection).

See [**this link**](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=46toCUvklIQC&pg=PA336&lpg=PA336&dq=Attribute+_NewEnum.VB_UserMemId+%3D+-4&source=bl&ots=jmNX0rGFK2&sig=2bJNwUXiVziowawP7bKwVbMdIcY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Z0ePUvaCO42Shgff-oC4Aw&ved=0CEUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Attribute%20_NewEnum.VB_UserMemId%20%3D%20-4&f=false) for a clearer explanation of the enumerable methods.

See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373081/how-to-use-the-implements-in-excel-vba/19379641#19379641) to better understand how the iteration is possible.

Comment: + 1 And one more way to check is using `Watch` Window :)

Comment: a Collection is also an Object so I'm not real sure what that proves? `typeof c is object` also returns True

Comment: @JosieP `Sheets` is a collection of `Object` type and not an object of `Collection` type which you have *proved* in your comment which I upvoted :) Didn't want to plagiarise your words so I have explained it differently

Comment: I know that :) my point was that your code doesn't seem to prove anything since `typeof c is object` also returns True just as `typeof Sheets is object` does. the original `typeof Sheets is Collection` actually already proved what I was saying

Comment: @SiddharthRout very nice of you to vote to delete my *highly* upvoted [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853685/vb-code-for-excel)

Comment: @mehow: Which one are you refering to?

Comment: Oh that one? That came up while I was reviewing tasks. Let me make it up to you. You lost 6 votes on that right. :)

Comment: @mehow: Please don't harass people for voting to delete low-quality questions that you took the time to answer. It was your choice to answer them in the first place.

Comment: And @Siddharth, you know that's just plain serial upvoting. Please don't do that sort of thing again.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on the (following my proposed hierarchy) "Iterable" interface (IUnknown/NewEnum() in VBA). It is now clear that both Collection class and (in my proposal) "cSheets" class implement the "Iterable" interface. Both clases share a common interface to be iterable. That makes sense. (continued in next comment)

Comment: The thing that doesn't make sense, as we have already discussed, is that they don't share a common interface to be treated as a collection. Both Collection class and cSheets class are collections, but they don't share a common "iCollection" interface. It looks like a big mistake from MS. I know, "ask MS why..." ;-)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Point Taken