# Array already dimensioned - Class module

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

For certain, technical, reasons, we cannot use styles in word. In an effort to speed up applying global properties over and over, I've created a class that can read from a simple xml style-sheet. The sheet contains different "paragraphs." Each paragraph simply stores the paragraph properties that we use the most.

I'm used to C++ where I can use dynamic memory and I'm trying to replicate the behavior of a dynamically allocated array. However, when I attempt to re-dim I get the error message "Array arleady dimensioned."

My research on the MSDN suggests that in order to ReDim the array has to be Global or in the "general declaration context" This makes me think it might simply not be possible to do it in a class.

Excerpt from MSDN:

> "You can use ReDim only at procedure level. Therefore, the declaration
>   context for the variable must be a procedure; it can't be a source
>   file, a namespace, an interface, a class, a structure, a module, or a
>   block."

I have attempted to search stack overflow for "Word VBA Array already dimensioned" and went through all 3 pages of results with no avail.

```
private type pStyle 'Definition removed because it's not needed
private Paragraphs(0) As pStyle 'Initially an empty array of paragraphs
```

later I have the following function

```
Public Function AddEmpty()

'Create space
count = count + 1
ReDim Preserve Paragraphs(count)
AddEmpty = count
End Function
```

Please let me know if any ideas. I would prefer to not have to "estimate" the number of paragraph styles we will need for each style sheet as every file is different.

Comment: normally, at least in VBA, if you don't know the amount of elements at compile time you go with a [Collection](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s239/collections.htm) or [Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure) or [CustomCollection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373081/how-to-use-the-implements-in-excel-vba/19379641#19379641).

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the VB data structures. In C++ there are several different dynamically sizable data structures. In this case a linked list would be perfect. I don't think there is anything really similar but a quick look at collection tells me it might be a good choice. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Private Paragraphs(0) As ...
```

This is not an empty array, rather it is a *fixed length* array with *1* element.

For a *dynamic array* - one you will later redimension - just declare it as:

```
Private Paragraphs() As ...
```

Comment: That got rid of the error. Of course it would be that simple :) thanks! I will accept the answer when the timer is up.

Comment: (Also worth noting that attempting to access an array of this type before its been `redim`d will result in an error)

Comment: I call ReDim immediately after I create the array specifically to avoid this.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim numbers(10) As Integer
MsgBox (UBound(numbers))
ReDim numbers(4)
MsgBox (UBound(numbers))
```

Above code will throw array-already-dimensioned. 
we can do like

```
ReDim numbers(10) As Integer
MsgBox (UBound(numbers))
ReDim numbers(4)
MsgBox (UBound(numbers))
```