# Excel VBA Place values in multidimensional array

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, vba

I have a worksheet with this type of structure (there are more columns in the real sheet, but not many):

```
ColumnAValue1   ColumnBValue1   23
ColumnAValue1   ColumnBValue1   45
ColumnAValue1   ColumnBValue1   2.4
ColumnAValue1   ColumnBValue2   1
ColumnAValue1   ColumnBValue2   3
ColumnAValue2   ColumnBValue1   5
ColumnAValue2   ColumnBValue1   6
ColumnAValue2   ColumnBValue1   7
ColumnAValue2   ColumnBValue2   355
ColumnAValue2   ColumnBValue2   221
```

And I want to get averages, item numbers and deviation for each combination (for example, ColumnAValue1 ColumnBValue1 would be the average of 23, 45 and 2.4). So I thought that getting all data in an Array, or Collection or Dictionary (I don't know if anything like "Multidimensional Dictionary" exists) would be useful. I wanted to end with a multidimentional array (or Collection) with a structure similar to this:

```
AllData(
        ColumnAValue1(
                    ColumnBValue1(23,45,2.4)
                    ColumnBValue2(1,3)
                    )
        ColumnAValue2(
                    ColumnBValue1(5,6,7)
                    ColumnBValue2(355,221)
                    )
        )
```

I know how to obtain unique values from columns.

My two questions:
**1)** How can I create an Array (or Collection) with the proper Keys (ColumnAValue1 and ColumnAValue2 for the first dimention, and ColumnBValue1 and ColumnBValue2 for the second), and **2)** then loop through all my data and "place" values in the corresponding subarray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Test()
  Dim c As Collection
  Set c = New Collection

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

  Dim i As Long
  For i = 1 To 10 'Assume 10 rows
    AddToLayeredCollection c, ws.Cells(i, 3).value, ws.Cells(i, 1).value, ws.Cells(i, 2).value 'Assume two columns for keys, A and B
  Next

  'Add 'c' to the watch window and examine it
End Sub

Public Sub AddToLayeredCollection(ByVal root_collection As Collection, ByVal value As Variant, ParamArray keys() As Variant)
  Dim i As Long
  Dim target_collection As Collection

  Set target_collection = root_collection
  For i = LBound(keys) To UBound(keys)
    Set target_collection = ResolveToCollection(target_collection, keys(i))
  Next

  target_collection.Add value
End Sub

Private Function ResolveToCollection(ByVal parent_collection As Collection, ByVal key As Variant) As Collection
  On Error Resume Next
  Set ResolveToCollection = parent_collection(key)(1)
  On Error GoTo 0

  If ResolveToCollection Is Nothing Then
    Set ResolveToCollection = New Collection
    parent_collection.Add Array(key, ResolveToCollection), key
  End If
End Function
```

The only reason I'm using the `Array()` thing is to be able to [retrieve keys from the collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5702524/11683). You can [use `Dictionary` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5702529/11683) and remove the `Array()`.

Comment: Wow! It does what i was asking! Still trying to get the logic of the code, but examining c in the watch windows (as you said) looks great. I'm amazed, and extremely grateful. I've been stuck four days with this before giving up and asking here...

Comment: @GSerg Between Dictionary and Array which one is more preferred approach in this case. Seeking your opinion as an enthusiast to learn from your valuable experience and expertise.

Comment: @skkakkar This is a question of personal preference. I tend to use `Collection` because it's an internal class and I know it's going to be available. Using a Dictionary would be cleaner in code, but that's a dependency on an external library - then again, the library is probably going to be present on any system where you run Excel - then again, read the [comments below this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5702529/11683).

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for enlightening me on this issue.

Comment: @GSerg One more, if you don't mind: how to count elements in subcollection? `CStr(c.Count)` is two in the example, and I can access elements like `c(1)(1)(1)(1)(1)` (it would be 23). But how could I know that the first group has 3 elements (23,45,2.4), and the second 2 (1,3)?

Comment: ok, got it: `c(1)(1)(1)(1).Count` and `c(1)(1)(2)(1).Count`. Still getting used to this "multidimensional collection". And still amazed with your skills...