# How to merge two collections in VBA?

Tags: vba, collections, merge

What's the most efficient way to merge two collections together in VBA, so that I have a 3rd Collection containing all of the items from the first two?

Comment: Why looking for the most efficient way to merge collections when arrays are already more efficient?

Comment: @FlorentB. That's just how my data's stored, I have to work with what I've got! But in the application that prompted me to ask this, I'm using collections because I'm constantly adding/removing, which I think collections *are* more efficient at that arrays? Or if what you're saying is that  writing the collections to a variant array then writing back to collection would be an efficient way of merging, then by all means, post and we can benchmark!

Comment: arrays are more efficient than collection even for adding/removing.

Comment: @FlorentB. except when they're misused, and resized at every single iteration ;-)

Comment: Have a look [here](http://mielk.pl/en/download/code/collection/joinCollections.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [this article](http://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/), which compares `For` vs `For Each` loops when iterating arrays, vs. when iterating object collections.

Bottom line:

- Use `For` loops to iterate arrays.
- Use `For Each` loops to iterate collections.

So, iterate your collections with `For Each` loops, and in these loops `Add` the items to your 3<sup>rd</sup> collection.

Comment: Fantastic, this is why you should post even if you think you know the answer! I suppose this is because `For ... Each` takes advantage of the un-ordered nature of a collection whereas `For i = 1 to Count` requires multiple lookups to a map?

Answer (score 3):

You can merge collections by looping through their items and adding them to either a new collection, or one of the original ones. *This does not preserve the keys in collection 2 though - you can't use collections if you want to do that*

If you want to add the items in `Collection` `col2` to another `Collection` `col1` and return a new merged `Collection`:

```
Function mergedCollection(ByVal col1 As Collection, ByVal col2 As Collection) As Collection
    'Add items from col2 to col1 and return the result
    'ByVal means we are only looking at copies of the collections (the values within them)
    'The function returns a NEW merged collection
    Dim i As Long 
    For i = 1 To col2.Count
        col1.Add col2.item(i)
    Next i
    Set mergedCollection = col1 'set return value
End Function
```

And to add `col2` to `col1` directly (`col1` is altered)

```
Sub mergeCollectionsInPlace(ByRef col1 As Collection, ByVal col2 As Collection)
    'Routine to add items from col 2 directly to col1
    'ByRef col1 means we are adding directly to the original col1
    'Routine doesn't return a new collection, it just appends col2 to col1
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To col2.Count 'loop through each item in collection 2
        col1.Add col2.item(i) 'add the item at index i to collection 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Use each like

```
Dim col3 As Collection
Set col3 = mergedCollection(col1, col2) 'sets col3 to be the merge of the two collections
mergeCollectionsInPlace(col1, col2)     'sets col1 to be the merge of the two collections
```

Comment: Using a `For` loop to iterate collections can't be *the most efficient way*.

Answer (score 1):

This function will merge any number of collections, using the type of loop specified in the accepted answer:

```
Function MergeCollections(ParamArray collections())
    Set MergeCollections = New Collection
    For i = LBound(collections) To UBound(collections)
        For Each c In collections(i)
            MergeCollections.Add c
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

Each collection goes in as a separate argument.

Note this doesn't preserve any keys, if any of your collections have keys, since that is not as simple.<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702362/vba-collection-list-of-keys)</sup>