# All properties of Application.ActiveSheet in Excel - Object Browser does not list the properties of Members

Tags: excel, vba, object, objectbrowser

Microsoft Docs do not list all the properties of Object `Application.ActiveSheet`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activesheet

It has only included some of the properties like: `ActiveSheet.Name`. But from VBA scripts I found on the internet, I know that there are more properties such as: `ActiveSheet.Type`

So I thought maybe I can list them all with this VBA code: from: [VBA collection: list of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702362/vba-collection-list-of-keys)

```
Sub AktivSheet()
Dim key As Variant
For Each key In Application.ActiveSheet
    Debug.Print "Key: " & key, "Value: " & Application.ActiveSheet.Item(key)
Next
End Sub
```

But it didn't work, and Microsoft Docs suggests to use Object Browser. But Object Browser does not list the properties for Application.ActiveSheet:

[image: ActiveSheet Object Browser]

I'm out of ideas! I just want a list of all ActiveSheet properties. Because I simply need to know the Text Direction of the Active Sheet, as in if it's Left to Right OR Right to Left.

Comment: `Activesheet` returns an `Object`, not a specific type, since it might not be a worksheet. If you want to know the properties of a `Worksheet`, look for *that* in the Object browser.

Comment: Thanks very much @Rory `Worksheet.DisplayRightToLeft` is what I needed. Now I can simply use `ActiveSheet.DisplayRightToLeft`, please write an answer. Also ActiveSheet and WorkSeet are both Objects? But as you said it might not be a WorkSheet, I see :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I just want a list of all ActiveSheet properties

You cannot easily get that programmatically with 100% VBA code, VBA has pretty much zero *reflection* capabilities.

Now, assuming we're *not* looking for a programmatic way to retrieve object properties, here's how to use the object browser to get what you're looking for.

First, right-click anywhere in the object browser and select the "Show hidden members" option to reveal the full breadth of the libraries you're looking at. This affects the names list dropdown when editing code: you'll be shown hidden members now.

One of the hidden modules in the Excel type library, is a module named `Global`, with a hidden `_Global` interface:

[image: Excel's Global module]

That hidden global module is how you can type `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name` and it "just works" (assuming there *is* an `ActiveSheet` - it could always blow up with error 91 when there's no active workbook open in the `Application` instance you're working with) even though you haven't specified what `Workbook` you're working with: implicitly, `ActiveSheet` is just working off whatever the `ActiveWorkbook` is.

So `ActiveSheet` is a *property*, not an object. It's a property that *returns* an object, but its declared type is `Object`.

This means any member call you make directly against `ActiveSheet`, is implicitly late-bound: you can type `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Naem` and VBA will happily compile the typo (`Option Explicit` can't save you here), and only blow up at run-time with error 438 "I can't find that property!".

In order to know what properties the `ActiveSheet` has, we need to know what *run-time* type we're looking at. And since a sheet in a `Workbook` object can be a `Worksheet`, a `Chart`, or several other types of legacy "sheet" objects, there is indeed no member accessible at compile-time, because at compile-time the `ActiveSheet` is just a pointer to an `Object`, and what type of object that is will only be known at run-time.

So instead of coding against `ActiveSheet`, we code against `Worksheet`, because we know the particular sheet we're expecting to work with is a `Worksheet` object.

```
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
```

Now when we type `Sheet.`, we're early-bound (types involved are known and resolved at compile-time) and helpfully provided with a list of all available members:

[image: member dropdown listing all members of a local Sheet object variable]

Every time you access a member (function, property) that returns an `Object` or a `Variant`, any member call made against it will be late-bound.

Strive to stay in the early-bound realm: declare local variables as needed, such that the compiler gets to "see" and validate everything! Try *typing* the below code to *feel* the difference - whenever you type a `.` dot and nothing comes up, it's a sign the compiler is losing sight of what's going on and you're possibly moving compile-time errors to run-time:

```
MsgBox ActiveSheet.DisplayRightToLeft '<~ late bound
```

```
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
MsgBox Sheet.DisplayRightToLeft '<~ early bound
```