# Get unique list with filtered range of another column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to extract the unique values in column B, for every unique value in column A.
I have a code from a post but it lists out the entire column's unique values.
What I want are only those unique values that are associated with the filter criteria I have provided.

I need to move these unique values to an array and use it for another sheet calculation.
The code I have so far is below.

```
Sub test()
    Dim TestRg As Excel.Range
    Dim Array1(200) As Variant
    Dim i, j As Integer
    i = 1
    
    Set TestRg = Range("L1:L181")
    TestRg.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        ActiveCell, Unique:=True
    For Each C In TestRg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Not (C) Is Nothing Then
        Array1(i) = C.Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Next C
    j = i - 1
    i = 1

    
    For i = 1 To j
    Debug.Print Array1(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Pl help.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799172/use-vba-to-get-unique-values-for-use-within-vba) on how to create unique values

Comment: The concept of "unique values in column B, for every unique value in column A" is a little strange. Combining your explanation in words with your code, should we understand that you need an array extracted from "A:B" columns after advanced filtering range applied on column "L:L", using a criteria and returning unique values?

Comment: What I am doing exactly is as below. Apply autofilter and select one value in col E. Col L contains many rows with many values repeating. So Use col L to list out all unique values and send the same to SQL server for query. Problem resolved with some modification to code provided below by @PGSystemTester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro will capture all distinct values of all visible cells in Column A of your activesheet and set the values in Column B. If rows are hidden in Column B, it may not display as you intend.

```
Sub findtheVisibleUniqueValues()
Dim sRange As Range, aCell As Range, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
ReDim zRay(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
i = 1

Set sRange = Intersect(ws.Range("A:A"), ws.UsedRange)

For Each aCell In sRange.Cells
    If aCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        'skip
    ElseIf Not (checkForMatch(aCell.Value, zRay)) Then
            ReDim Preserve zRay(1 To 1, 1 To i)
            zRay(1, i) = aCell.Value
            i = i + 1
    End If

Next aCell

'Your array is complete.
'This will insert to Column B (note if rows are hidden, it may not display correctly)

ws.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(zRay, 2), 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(zRay)

End Sub



Private Function checkForMatch(theValue As Variant, theArray()) As Boolean
Dim g As Long, j As Long

For j = LBound(theArray) To UBound(theArray)
    For g = LBound(theArray, 2) To UBound(theArray, 2)
        If theValue = theArray(j, g) Then
            checkForMatch = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next g
Next j

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked with little modification and some addition of code.