# How to find and pull out duplicate text fields in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have about 80,000 emails in one column of MS Excel 2010.

Some of them are duplicates and I need to find and pull those duplicates. I want the duplicates in a separate document.

Right now I can find them and highlight them in red using the Conditional Formatting function that's built right into Excel (Home tab > conditional formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > Duplicate Values) but that literally just highlights them.

There's also Remove Duplicates, which obviously just deletes them; Not what I want either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using VBA you can enter them into a dictionary. Have a look at the excellent answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array

Comment: Can you use a helper column? Should be easy to do this with a helper column, and autofilter.

Comment: I'll give that a look, but I was told that VBA runs extremely slowly, especially for the amount I want it to sift through. Thanks though!

Comment: Highlight the duplicates as you describe above. Go to Data->Sort->Sort On->Cell Color. Copy/paste those out to another column or whatever. So easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a pretty easy way to do it:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$15,A1)>1,A1,"")
```

[image: Example1]
Autofill that down column B.

And then just do a remove dulicates on column B:
[image: Example2]

And then you can sort any cell in column B with values to the top. Good Luck.

Comment: This formula is exactly the lines I am working with, however, could this formula be modified so that in column B it concatenates the duplicate value it matches too? In my sheet the some of the duplicates have a few extra zeros in front of the value it is matching and I would like to be able to reference in the same cell the duplicate it is matching