# Remove Duplicates from Range always leaves 1 blank cell at the end

Tags: vba, excel

As part of a larger macro, I'm trying to copy a range from one sheet to another sheet, remove the duplicates, and set the remaining unique values as a range. I've written the below that works in principal, but after removing duplicates and setting the remaining cells as a range, the last cell in the range is always a blank one. How can I ignore this blank cell, so my range is on the unique values?

```
lr = Data.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Data.Range("B5:B" & lr).Copy Sheets("Index").Range("B1")
Sheets("Index").Range("B1:B10000").Copy
Sheets("Index").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Index").Range("B1:B10000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Application.CutCopyMode = False
lr = Sheets("Index").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set MCH = Sheets("Index").Range("B1:B" & lr)
```

FYI the reason I'm copying paste values with the range is because its copying a 'helper' column that combines 2 names, and my macro didn't work without doing that. If there is a more efficient way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gary's Student has noted there will be a blank row in the hard-coded range `"B1:B10000"`.

Try using your last row logic again to adjust the 10000 - I think as you are pasting from `B5` you can adjust from `lr` to `(lr+4)`:

```
lr = Data.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(Excel.xlUp).Row
Data.Range("B5:B" & lr).Copy Sheets("Index").Range("B1")
Sheets("Index").Range("B1:B" & (lr+4)).Copy
Sheets("Index").Range("B1").PasteSpecial Excel.xlPasteValues
Sheets("Index").Range("B1:B" & (lr+4)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=Excel.xlNo
Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False
lr = Sheets("Index").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(Excel.xlUp).Row
Set MCH = Sheets("Index").Range("B1:B" & lr)
```

A very different, but much prettier approach, is to use an array and collection like this:

```
Sub unique()
  Dim arr As New Collection, a
  Dim aFirstArray() As Variant
  Dim i As Long

  Dim Data as Excel.worksheet
  Set Data = Thisworkbook.sheets("Data")

  lr = Data.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(Excel.xlUp).Row
  aFirstArray() = Data.Range("B5:B" & lr)

  On Error Resume Next
  For Each a In aFirstArray
     arr.Add a, a
  Next

  For i = 1 To arr.Count
     Sheets("Index").Cells(i, 2) = arr(i)
  Next

End Sub
```

Arrays are very fast - I'd imagine this is also quicker.

I wish this second scipt was my original piece of code but it is an adaptation. Reference:
[vba: get unique values from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array)

Comment: Much more elegant, thank you for your help!
I did notice that I had to replace aFirstArray() with aFirstArray to make it work, but much faster after that.

Answer (score 0):

If there are cells in a column that contain *Nulls* before duplicates are removed; then at least one cell containing a *Null* will be in the column after duplicates are removed.

You can remove the *Null* afterwards.