# Excel vba Function with return

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, return

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3017973/3841056) for my problem. And it works fine like this:

```
Dim CNPJs As New Collection, a
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range

U_L = Plan2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next
For Each rng In Plan2.Range("A2:A" & U_L)
    CNPJs.Add rng.value, rng.value
Next
```

But now I want to bulid a function that returns this unique array, because I will use this many times...  I tried this:

```
Public Function unArray(myRange As Range) As Collection

    Dim arr As Collection, a

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each rng In myRange
        arr.Add rng.value, rng.value
    Next

    unArray = arr

End Function
```

And I call it:

```
Sub test()

      Dim CNPJs As New Collection, a

      U_L = Plan2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

      CNPJs = unArray(Plan2.Range("A2:A" & U_L))

End Sub
```

But it returns this error:

[image]
"*Compilation error:*"
"*The argument is required"*

Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think you need to use `Set`. `Set CNPJs = unArray(Plan2.Range("A2:A" & U_L))`... Also use `New` for the collection in the function...

Comment: It works!!! Thanks man! I also had to use `Set` here: `Set unArray = arr`  . Please post as answer and I will acept it.

Comment: I'm just on phone right now. But would need to explain why to post a suitable answer... maybe later... still, I don't mind the points. You got it to work, that is all that counts for me ;)

Comment: ok, but I need to chose an answer, please post it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection is an object and needs to be treated like one, means you need to `Set` it. But keep in mind that this action just creates a pointer to the range inside your RAM.
For your case just use:

```
Set CNPJs = unArray(Plan2.Range("A2:A" & U_L))
```

That said, it doesn't matter for your code, but having 2 collections while one is `Set` to the other, alternating one of them will also effect the other.

If you still have questions, just ask. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
U_L = Plan2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

This will return a long or integer.  A range requires a string and therefore you need to convert U_L to a string when referencing it in a range.

```
CNPJs = unArray(Plan2.Range("A2:A" & CStr(U_L)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not true. `"A" & variable` will be a string in the first place. (As long as `variable` is no object which would throw an error (still will work if the object is a pointer to a non-object variable like `Range` or `Cells`)). At the other hand, `Range(Cells(1 ,1))` will also work and it is just a pointer (no string or numerical variable). ;)

Comment: Is this a recent change to excel, because I have certainly received errors by doing this in the past.  I don't understand how you can concatenate a string with an integer and not get an error