# Counting unique values in a VBA collection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA collection that contains several File items (I created a class module called File with several properties). I was curious if there is a way to use a `For` loop to iterate through all the items in the collection and do two things:

1. Get a list of all unique items based on a File property that I specify
2. Count the number of items that match each unique value from the above list

For example, let's say I have 4 File items in my collection:

- File1 (File1.Pattern = "Test*.xlsx")
- File2 (File2.Pattern = "Test*.xlsx")
- File3 (File3.Pattern = "Test*.txt")
- File4 (File4.Pattern = "Test*.csv")

The output I would want would be (ideally an array or separate collection):

- Test*.xlsx (2)
- Test*.txt (1)
- Test*.csv (1)

Any thoughts on how I might implement something like this?

Comment: Declare variables for each pattern then increment them for each match through loop?

Comment: What if you don't know in advance what patterns there are @findwindow?

Comment: What @GSerg said. There can be an infinite amount of patterns.

Comment: @GSerg I guess the number of file extensions can approach infinity so make a loop first to grab all of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vba: get unique values from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array)

Comment: @EliGreenberg Just create a new collection, using the property that you want to get the unique count on as the `Key`.  Use an `On error resume next` to ignore the errors caused by trying to add duplicate keys.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Great idea until Tim gave me an even better idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't need to do this on a Mac:

```
Dim d, f, k
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

For Each f in myFiles
    d(f.Pattern) = d(f.Pattern)+1
Next f

For Each k in d
    Debug.Print k, d(k) 
Next k
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim.