# Excel VBA How to append column of value to array?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I would like to search through a column of data and compare the values. If a value is not in the array, then I want to append the value to the array. Otherwise, I keep looking through each row. I'm having a little trouble with the syntax. Can I get some help?

When I run this I get an error saying "Invalid Procedure call or argument" on the IsError(Application.Match(cells(i, 4).Value, codeArr, False)) function.

```
For i = 1 To 17381
  If IsError(Application.Match(cells(i, 1).Value, codeArr, False)) Then

    ReDim Preserve codeArr(count)
    codeArr(count) = cells(i, 1)
    count = count + 1
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: What is `codeArr`? You can't match an entire array like that.

Comment: codeArr is just the name of my array. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array

Comment: Thanks Scott, I was looking at this earlier. However, the dimension of that array was fixed. I needed to secure an infinite dimension for different data files, which is what I included ReDim to resize my array everytime I add a string into my array

Comment: That is the beauty of using either the dictionary or the collection.  It will grow as needed.  You can iterate through a variable range and try to add each one, if it is a duplicate it will not be added.  If it is unique it will be.  In the end you end up with a collection or dictionary of only unique values.  You do not need to declare a size to dictionary or collection just keep adding.  Then you  can pull from them to create your unique list.

Comment: How is `codeArr` initialised?  If it is un-initialised you will get this error.  Try adding `Redim codeArr(1 to 1)` at the start of the code or see cpearons [IsArrayAllocated](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/isarrayallocated.aspx)

Comment: codeArr is initialized as a Variant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this UDF

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1
End Function
```

and then replace

```
If IsError(Application.Match(cells(i, 1).Value, codeArr, False)) Then
```

with

```
If Not IsInArray(cells(i, 1).Value, codeArr) Then
```

I believe it'll accomplish what you're after.

**EDIT** 
Example input:

```
Dim codeArr As Variant
codeArr = Array(4, 5, 6)
cnt = 4 'Use this instead of Count as Count is a reserved word
```

If Column A had 1,2,3 and 4 in rows 1, 2, 3 and 4, respectively, then `codeArr` would contain the values (4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3) if you looped `i = 1 to 4`.

Comment: Thanks Matt, should If IsInArray(cells(i,1).Value) Then be If IsInArray(cells(i,1).Value,arr)? Would you also happen to know why my ReDim Preserve arr(count) is invalid?

Comment: I made an edit. Should be `IsInArray(cells(i, 1).Value, codeArr)`. `ReDim Preserve ...` should work fine. Can we see your array?

Comment: I corrected my ReDim but at the moment andother error within the function popped up
IsInArray = UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1 saying "subscription out of range

Comment: What is in your array?

Comment: And what is in column A?

Comment: my array starts as empty and column A consist a bunch of 3 digit numbers. Most are the same, some may be different. And I would like to store the different ones

Comment: I just checked the code and it's not enter this if statement:
    
    'If Not IsInArray(cells(i, 1).Value, codeArr) Then'

Comment: I added an edit last night that I hope will help guide you for your specific program. Please let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: This is what I have so far
    `If IsInArray(cells(i, 1).Value, codeArr) Then
            ReDim Preserve codeArr(1 To cnt)
            codeArr(cnt) = cells(i, 1).Value
            cnt = cnt + 1             
            MsgBox codeArr
        End If'
And the IsInArray function is as you suggested, but its going into the if at the moment.

Comment: I believe you need `If Not ...`

Comment: OK. Good. I was worried we had more work to do yet. Glad all is well.