# Is there a formula to trim a cell of all duplicate values and zeroes?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, I have Cell A1 that has "4, 0, 0, 0, 4" and I want to know if I can input a formula in B to spit out just "4".

```
+==================================================+===================================+
|                    Col A  - Source               |  Col B  - Result on referencing Col A
+==================================================+===================================+
| 4, 0, 0, 0, 4                                    | 4                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| 268, 0, 0, 0, 268                                | 268                               |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| 282, 283, 0, 0, 0, 0                             | 282, 283                          |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| 0, 0, 0, 0, 0                                    |                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| 0, 0, 4324, 4325, 4326, 0, 4324                  | 4324, 4325, 4326                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| 450, 1307, 1308, 1309, 1310, 1321, 0, 0, 0, 1309 | 450, 1307, 1308, 1309, 1310, 1321 |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array

Comment: Getting rid of the 0 is easy using substitute, the problem is removing the duplicates.  It will take vba.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the zeros with this formula `=SUBSTITUTE(A2&",","0,","")` but you'll need use some VBA or the remove duplicates button to remove duplicates values.

The alternative is to apply "Data" => "Text in column" to the column A and then extract the max value. This will ignore zeros and will extract one number for each rows. But will not extract multiple values like `282, 283`.