# How to make a public dictionary in an Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have something like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
'(...do something related to alpha...)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Set alpha = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'(...do something like add keys and values to the alpha dictionary...)
End Sub
```

I'm really new at VBA and I noticed that `alpha` dictionary can only be used inside `UserForm_Activate`, so I want to make a global variable in order to use it also in `ComboBox1_Change`.

But I can't.

I tried with something more simple, like an integer.

```
Public x as Integer

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
MsgBox(x)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
x = 5
End Sub
```

And this work, but if I do something similar but with a dictionary (`Public alpha as Scripting.Dictionary`), it raise (from spanish) "Compilation error: It wasn't defined the type defined by the user". I don't know what to do.

Comment: Set your variable outside sub `Public alpha As Scripting.Dictionary`

Comment: See [get unique values from array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3017950/4408538) for an example in action.

Comment: @0m3r Error: "Compilation error: It wasn't defined the type defined by the user".

Comment: You will need to set a reference

Comment: @0m3r, What is that?

Comment: To add the reference to your VBA project, go to the VB Editor, and select Tools --> References from the menu.  Select Microsoft Scripting Runtime from the list of installed libraries, and click OK.

Comment: And then use `Set alpha  = New Scripting.Dictionary`

Comment: @0m3r, sorry, but what are you talking about "set a reference"?

Comment: Read something about `scope of variables` [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications) or [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx). And read about `scripting dictionary` e.g. [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/). And in case you didn't use `Option Explicit` then try to use it. HTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a Public object withing a Form's Class module is a bad idea. Unless the object should be accessible only within the class, thus the accessibility should be changed to `Private`, consider having it in a Standard module.

You could also expose it by a Public property so you don't have to worry about the object's construction.

```
Private objAlpha As Object

Public Property Get Alpha() As Object
    If objAlpha Is Nothing Then Set objAlpha = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set Alpha = objAlpha
End Property
```

To call it:

```
If Alpha.Exists("SomeText") Then
    '...
End If
```

This way it can be referenced anywhere in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Public Alpha As Object` above everything. Then Alpha can be change to a dictionary using `Set alpha = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`.