# VBA to filter and send email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

I am trying to automate the email process which we have been sending to various stack holders.

I wanted to filter the column D based on company code and send out the email to the people listed in O column ( the email should not be duplicated), and also need to include CC (without duplicates)

[image]

Below is the VBA which am trying, but could not include the TO and CC.

```
Sub Send_Row_Or_Rows_2()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Ash As Worksheet
    Dim Cws As Worksheet
    Dim Rcount As Long
    Dim Rnum As Long
    Dim FilterRange As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Integer
    Dim StrBody As String
    Dim StrBody2 As String
    Dim FileToAttach As String
    Dim RngTo As Range

    Set RngTo = Ash.Columns("H").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    StrBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Dear Approver,<p>Please be informed that below invoices are waiting for your approval in BasWare for more than 10 days.  Please check them and take action accordingly as soon as possible.</BODY>"

    'On Error GoTo cleanup
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Set filter sheet, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
    Set Ash = Worksheets("rawdata")

    'Set filter range and filter column (column with e-mail addresses)
    Set FilterRange = Ash.Range("A4:M" & Ash.Rows.Count)
    FieldNum = 4                                 'Filter column = D because the filter range start in column A

    'Add a worksheet for the unique list and copy the unique list in A1
    Set Cws = Worksheets.Add
    FilterRange.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=Cws.Range("A1"), _
        CriteriaRange:="", Unique:=True

    'Count of the unique values + the header cell
    Rcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cws.Columns(1))

    'If there are unique values start the loop
    If Rcount >= 2 Then
        For Rnum = 2 To Rcount

            'Filter the FilterRange on the FieldNum column
            FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                                   Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value
            'If the unique value is a mail addres create a mail
            If Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value Like "?*?*?*" Then

                With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                End With

                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

                On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .To = Ash.Cells(Rnum, 15).Value
                    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "CDM_Basware_Administration@esab.com"
                    .CC = sCC
                    .Subject = "Reminder - Pending Invoices - More than 10 days"
                    .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & signature
                    FileToAttach = "C:\Users\gyousz\Desktop\Weekly_Customer CL3 and PT Control file_May_2018"
                    .Display
                End With

                On Error GoTo 0

                Set OutMail = Nothing
            End If

            'Close AutoFilter
            Ash.AutoFilterMode = False

        Next Rnum
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Any help on this highly appreciated.

Comment: You have some strange things in your code (setting `RngTo` but never using it, using a variable `sCC` that is never defined nor assigned), but what exactly is your question?

Comment: Can I use filter? Can I remove duplicates (change your rawdata sheet)? Can I create another sheet?

Comment: Should this macro send an email per company code? or just one email for specific company code?

Answer (score 1):

Please divide your codes into separate functions:

- One for getting recipients
- One to send email

I have recreated your workbook. Code below would do the ff:

- Get all company codes first
- Filter list by company codes
- Get TO and CC list
- Send email

Only modification left here is creating another function for sending email (and pass the variables).

```
    Sub Send_Row_Or_Rows_2()
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

        ' Initialization
        ' ==================================================
        Dim shtRec As Worksheet: Set shtRec = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("rawdata")
        Dim intLastRow As Long, intLastCol As Long ' for end cell
        Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, rngCell As Range ' for loops
        Dim rngFilter As Range ' filter range
        Dim strEmailTO As String, strEmailCC As String ' recipients

        Dim arrCoCd() As String ' company codes
        Dim arrEmailTO() As String ' TO recipients
        Dim arrEmailCC() As String ' CC recipients

        Dim arrEmailRec() As String, strEmailRec As String ' temporary variables

        ' Get Recipient header column indexes
        Dim intRowHead As Integer: intRowHead = 4 ' header row
        Dim intColCoCd As Integer: intColCoCd = 1 ' company code column
        Dim intColTo   As Integer:   intColTo = 3 ' TO column
        Dim intColCc   As Integer:   intColCc = 4 ' CC column

        ' Filter Recipients by Company Code
        ' ==================================================
        With shtRec
            ' Remove filter
            If Not .AutoFilter Is Nothing Then .AutoFilterMode = False

            ' Get end cell
            With .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
                intLastRow = .Row
                intLastCol = .Column
            End With

            ' Add filter
            Set rngFilter = .Range(Cells(intRowHead, 1), Cells(intLastRow, intLastCol))
            rngFilter.AutoFilter

            ' Get list of company codes
            ' =========================
            ReDim arrCoCd(1 To intLastRow)
            For i = (intRowHead + 1) To intLastRow ' exclude header
                With .Cells(i, intColCoCd)
                    If .Value <> vbNullString Then
                        k = k + 1
                        arrCoCd(k) = VBA.Trim(.Value)
                    End If
                End With
            Next i

            ' Reset variable
            k = 0

            ' Get unique values
            ' =========================
            arrCoCd = FnStrUniqueArray(arrCoCd)

            ' Filter by Company Code
            For i = LBound(arrCoCd) To UBound(arrCoCd)
                If arrCoCd(i) <> vbNullString Then
                    rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=intColCoCd, Criteria1:="=" & arrCoCd(i)
                    While Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone: DoEvents: Wend

                    ' Get list only if with results
                    If .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(intColCoCd).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
                        Dim strRng As String

                        ' Get TO list
                        ' =========================
                        ' Loop each visible cell in TO column
                        k = 0
                        strRng = .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns(intColTo).Address(False, False)

                        For Each rngCell In .Range(strRng)
                            ' Remove spaces
                            strEmailRec = VBA.Trim(VBA.Replace(rngCell.Value, " ", ""))

                            ' Get email addresses
                            arrEmailRec = VBA.Split(strEmailRec, ";")

                            ' Add email addresses to list
                            If k = 0 Then k = k + 1 Else k = UBound(arrEmailTO) + 1
                            ReDim Preserve arrEmailTO(1 To k)

                            For j = LBound(arrEmailRec) To UBound(arrEmailRec)
                                arrEmailTO(k) = arrEmailRec(j)
                            Next j

                            ' Remove duplicates in list
                            arrEmailTO = FnStrUniqueArray(arrEmailTO)

                            ' Reset variables
                            strEmailRec = vbNullString
                            Erase arrEmailRec
                        Next rngCell

                        ' Get CC list
                        ' =========================
                        ' Loop each visible cell in CC column
                        k = 0
                        strRng = .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns(intColCc).Address(False, False)

                        For Each rngCell In .Range(strRng)
                            ' Remove spaces
                            strEmailRec = VBA.Trim(VBA.Replace(rngCell.Value, " ", ""))

                            ' Get email addresses
                            arrEmailRec = VBA.Split(strEmailRec, ";")

                            ' Add email addresses to list
                            If k = 0 Then k = k + 1 Else k = UBound(arrEmailCC) + 1
                            ReDim Preserve arrEmailCC(1 To k)

                            For j = LBound(arrEmailRec) To UBound(arrEmailRec)
                                arrEmailCC(k) = arrEmailRec(j)
                            Next j

                            ' Remove duplicates in list
                            arrEmailCC = FnStrUniqueArray(arrEmailCC)

                            ' Reset variables
                            strEmailRec = vbNullString
                            Erase arrEmailRec
                        Next rngCell
                    End If

                    ' Join recipients list
                    strEmailTO = VBA.Join(arrEmailTO, ";")
                    strEmailCC = VBA.Join(arrEmailCC, ";")

                    ' Send email
                    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                    Dim strSubject As String: strSubject = "Reminder - Pending Invoices - More than 10 days"
                    Dim strAttachment As String: strAttachment = "C:\Users\gyousz\Desktop\Weekly_Customer CL3 and PT Control file_May_2018"
                    Dim strSendOnBehalf As String: strSendOnBehalf = "CDM_Basware_Administration@esab.com"
                    On Error Resume Next
                    With OutMail
                        .To = strEmailTO
                        .SentOnBehalfOfName = strSendOnBehalf
                        .CC = strEmailCC
                        .Subject = strSubject
                        .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & signature
                        .Attachments.Add strAttachment
                        .Display
                    End With

                    On Error GoTo 0

                    ' Reset variables
                    Erase arrEmailTO
                    Erase arrEmailCC
                End If
            Next i

        End With

    ErrorHandler:

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With

    End Sub
```

Here is the code to remove duplicates in arrays.
Reference:[vba get unique values from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array)

```
Function FnStrUniqueArray(aTmpArray() As String)
    Dim ctr As Long, cTmpCollection As New Collection, cTmpCollect

    For Each cTmpCollect In aTmpArray
       cTmpCollection.Add cTmpCollect, cTmpCollect
    Next

    ' convert collection to array
    ReDim aTmpArray(1 To cTmpCollection.Count)
    For ctr = 1 To cTmpCollection.Count
        aTmpArray(ctr) = cTmpCollection(ctr)
    Next ctr

    Set cTmpCollection = Nothing
    FnStrUniqueArray = aTmpArray
End Function
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything.. there are no email sending options.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would like to know what your results look like now but you could do the following -- you would need to sort your sheet by Company

```
DIM TheToList, TheCCList, CurrRow


CurrRow = 1

Do until --end of the sheet is reached ---
TheToList = ""
TheCCList = ""

if cells(CurrRow, 4) = cells(CurrRow-1,4) then    ' same company
  ' I was wrong >>> if instr(1,TheCCList,cells(CurrRow,15)) = 0   then ' diff TO
  if instr(1,TheToList,cells(CurrRow,15)) = 0   then ' diff TO
        TheToList = TheToList & cells(CurrRow,15) & "; "
    end if
    if instr(1,TheCCList,cells(CurrRow,16)) = 0   then ' diff CC
        TheCCList = TheCCList & cells(CurrRow,16) & "; "
    end if
else
    if CurrRow <> 1 then  
         ' do your output here because the company has changed
         ' probably call a subroutine because you will need it at the end too 
    end if
    TheToList = ""
    TheCCList = ""
end if
CurrRow = CurrRow + 1

Loop

' call your output subroutine one more time
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with your code, but it composing several emails based on the To list in column 15 and not on unique company code. 

The final output should be like, the code should filter column D and send out a mail to the To list mentioned in the Column O. The challenge here is that the Column O contains a repetitive email address.

Comment: Ahh ... I see a typo I made ...  the first instr should be with TheToList, not the CCList.    I'll edit the response now.   If that doesn't fix it, let me know.  I'll admit I haven't tested the solution

Answer (score 0):

I will address the problem of creating unique emailTO and emailCC from Cws sheet.
For this i suggest you use dictionaries.

Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' as per screenshot.
[image]

Also given an improvement and suggestion on how to attach the file.

```
Sub Send_Row_Or_Rows_2()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Ash As Worksheet
    Dim Cws As Worksheet
    Dim Rcount As Long
    Dim Rnum As Long
    Dim FilterRange As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Integer
    Dim StrBody As String
    Dim StrBody2 As String
    Dim FileToAttach As String
    Dim RngTo As Range

    Set RngTo = Ash.Columns("H").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    StrBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Dear Approver,<p>Please be informed that below invoices are waiting for your approval in BasWare for more than 10 days.  Please check them and take action accordingly as soon as possible.</BODY>"

    'On Error GoTo cleanup
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Set filter sheet, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
    Set Ash = Worksheets("rawdata")

    'Set filter range and filter column (column with e-mail addresses)
    Set FilterRange = Ash.Range("A4:M" & Ash.Rows.Count)
    FieldNum = 4                                 'Filter column = D because the filter range start in column A

    'Add a worksheet for the unique list and copy the unique list in A1
    Set Cws = Worksheets.Add
    FilterRange.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=Cws.Range("A1"), _
        CriteriaRange:="", Unique:=True

    'Count of the unique values + the header cell
    Rcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cws.Columns(1))

    'If there are unique values start the loop
    If Rcount >= 2 Then

        'find unique emails for TO as CC
        Dim dictTO As New Dictionary
        Dim dictCC As New Dictionary
        Dim emailTO As String
        Dim emailCC As String

        For Rnum = 2 To Rcount
            emailTO = Trim(UCase(Cws.Range("O" & Rnum).Value))
            emailCC = Trim(UCase(Cws.Range("P" & Rnum).Value))
            If Not (emailTO = "") Then
                If Not dictTO.Exists(emailTO) Then
                    Call dictTO.Add(emailTO, emailTO)
                End If
            End If
            If Not (emailCC = "") Then
                If Not dictCC.Exists(emailCC) Then
                    Call dictCC.Add(emailCC, emailCC)
                End If
            End If
        Next Rnum

        'remove CC emails that are in To dict
        For Rnum = 1 To dictTO.Count
            If dictCC.Exists(dictTO.Item(Rnum)) Then
                dictCC.Remove (dictTO.Item(Rnum))
            End If
        Next

        emailTO = ""
        emailCC = ""

        'Generate To Addresses
        For Rnum = 1 To dictTO.Count
            emailTO = emailTO & dictTO.Item(Rnum) & ","
        Next

        'Generate CC Addresses
        For Rnum = 1 To dictTO.Count
            emailCC = emailCC & dictCC.Item(Rnum) & ","
        Next

        With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        FileToAttach = "C:\Users\gyousz\Desktop\Weekly_Customer CL3 and PT Control file_May_2018"
        'fixed file being attached everytime - maybe saved a copy of Cws sheet and attach the workbook

        On Error Resume Next
        Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
        With OutMail
            .To = emailTO
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "CDM_Basware_Administration@esab.com"
            .CC = emailCC
            .Subject = "Reminder - Pending Invoices - More than 10 days"
            .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & Signature
            If (fso.FileExists(File)) Then 'checking if file exists
                .Attachments.Add FileToAttach 'corrected how to add an attachment
            End If
            .Display
        End With

        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing


        'Close AutoFilter
        Ash.AutoFilterMode = False


    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

try manipulating this;

```
Sub sendmail10101()
    Dim obApp As Object
    Dim NewMail As MailItem

    Set obApp = Outlook.Application
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'You can change the concrete info as per your needs
    With NewMail
         .Subject = Cells(21, 3).Value
         .To = Cells(18, 3).Value
         .Body = "Good day" & vbCrLf & "i hope you are keeping well " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "please can you assist with the below members infomation;" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Cells(20, 3).Value
         '.Attachments.Add ("C:\Attachments\Test File.docx") IF YOU WANT TO ADD AN ATTACHMENT 
         .Importance = olImportanceHigh
         .Display 'YOU CAN CHANGE TO SEND WHEN READY TO AUTOMATE 
    End With
    Set obApp = Nothing
    Set NewMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

instead of duplicating run the for loop;

for i = 1 to 20 at start of code

cells(i,1) where the data to be looped

next i before end sub

and you can use a filer add on at the beginning of the code to filter before starting the loop (obviously make sure that you set a filter on the data before using this type of code);

```
Sub AutoFilter_Text_Examples()
'Examples for filtering columns with TEXT
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim iCol As Long
  'Set reference to the first Table on the sheet
  Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
  'Set filter field
  iCol = lo.ListColumns("Product").Index

  'Clear Filters
  lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

  'All lines starting with .AutoFilter are a continuation
  'of the with statement.
  With lo.Range

    'Single Item
    .AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:="Product 2"

    '2 Criteria using Operator:=xlOr
    .AutoFilter Field:=iCol, _
                Criteria1:="Product 3", _
                Operator:=xlOr, _
                Criteria2:="Product 4"

    'More than 2 Criteria (list of items in an Array function)
    .AutoFilter Field:=iCol, _
                Criteria1:=Array("Product 4", "Product 5", "Product 7"), _
                Operator:=xlFilterValues

    'Begins With - use asterisk as wildcard character at end of string
    .AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:="Product*"

    'Ends With - use asterisk as wildcard character at beginning
    'of string
    .AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:="*2"

    'Contains - wrap search text in asterisks
    .AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:="*uct*"

    'Does not contain text
    'Start with Not operator <> and wrap search text in asterisks
    .AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:="<>*8*"

    'Contains a wildcard character * or ?
    'Use a tilde ~ before the character to search for values with
    'wildcards
    .AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:="Product 1~*"

  End With
End Sub
```

and to clear filter;

```
Sub Clear_All_Table_Filters_On_Sheet()
Dim lo As ListObject

  'Loop through all Tables on the sheet
  For Each lo In Sheet1.ListObjects

    'Clear All Filters for entire Table
    lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

  Next lo
End Sub
```

so you can use a message box which sets the filter and then triggers the automated mail depending on what you require and the filter gets undone and resets for next use.