# VBA get unique values from array explanation

Tags: excel, vba

I have found this code but I have hard times understanding it. Could you please explain it in details?

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array?answertab=active#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array?answertab=active#_=_)

```
    Sub unique() 
  Dim arr As New Collection, a 
  Dim aFirstArray() As Variant 
  Dim i As Long 

  aFirstArray() = Array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Tomato", "Apple", _ 
  "Lemon", "Lime", "Lime", "Apple") 

  On Error Resume Next 
  For Each a In aFirstArray 
     arr.Add a, a 
  Next 

  For i = 1 To arr.Count 
     Cells(i, 1) = arr(i) 
  Next 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding comments to each line:

```
Sub unique()

    'Declare a collection object called `arr`. Despite the name, it's not an array. Also declare the variable `a` as type variant (default)
    Dim arr As New Collection, a

    'Declare an array of type variant, being used here in this example and it will be loaded with fruit names.
    Dim aFirstArray() As Variant

    'Declare a variable called `i` as a long integer type
    Dim i As Long


    'Here's are our example single-dimensional array for which we want to find unique values.
    aFirstArray() = Array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Tomato", "Apple", _
    "Lemon", "Lime", "Lime", "Apple")

    'If we encounter an error adding `aFirstArray` array elements/items into our `arr` collection object then ignore them
    On Error Resume Next

    'Loop through each element(fruit name) in the array `aFirstArray`
    For Each a In aFirstArray

        'Add the item to the collection. The key and the value are both being set to the fruitname which is now in variable `a`
        'If the key (fruit name) already exists, that `On Error Resume Next` will ignore the error that pops.
        arr.Add a, a
    Next

    'Now we have a collection object `arr` that contains unique values from the array held in both the key and value of each item.
    'Iterate from 1 to the however many unique items are in the collection object `arr`
    For i = 1 To arr.Count

        'Print the value (fruitname) out to the workbook
        Cells(i, 1) = arr(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

The reason that a `collection` object is being used here is that it works much like an array, but instead of an index holding a value, we can set a `key`. Keys must be unique, so when we try to add that same key AFTER it's already been set with a `value` it errors out. What you end up with is a collection object with unique keys (and in this case a matching value) from the array.

You'll see similar versions of this subroutine/function using Dictionary objects as well. I prefer those over collections since a [dictionary object has a method `exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object), so instead of `On Error Resume Next` which is more of a crutch, you can check if the `key` already exists in your dictionary before adding `If Not myDictionary.Exists(keyvalue) Then myDictionary.Add keyValue, val`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was hard to understand those variables and their functions since they were not fully explained before!

Answer (score 0):

`aFirstArray() = ...` creates an array with value that aren't (necessarily) unique.

The next block of code attempts to add each of these items to a `Collection`, and uses the `On Error Resume Next` to ignore the error that would otherwise raise if you attempt to add an already-existing-item to the collection, thus ensuring the `arr` (Collection) contains only the unique values from the array.

From the dox on the [`Collection.Add` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/add-method-visual-basic-for-applications):

> An error also occurs if a specified key duplicates the key for an existing member of the collection.