# Excel Array Query distinct query

Tags: excel

I have a  query, could anybody please help. My query is, i want to extract distinct/unique values from an array. For example:
my array is {A,A,A,B,B,C,C,C,D,D}, the resultant should also be an array but only with distinct values {A,B,C,D}. Only excel formula required, i already have a function written but UDF"s cannot  be used in data validation list, so cant use it.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. I would suggest you add that UDF. It will give a starting point for any answer... For unique values in VBA array [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3017973/9808063)

Comment: Also, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml/61837697?r=SearchResults&s=2|0.0000#61837697) for extracting unique values using FILTERXML Function.

Comment: Where is that data? Is it in VBA? Is it in the worksheet?

Comment: So, basically my problem is that i have extracted a list that contains duplicates. This list is being passed on to data validation list argument to make use of drop down functionality. Since, this list is not a unique value list, it repeats which i want to avoid. i hope you got my query.

Answer (score 3):

If the data is in a worksheet, you can use the Unique() function (available only in Excel 365) to create a list of unique values to use in a Data Validation source.

Formula in B2 (note that it spills down automatically, without dragging down)

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A11)
```

[image]

The Data Validation can then refer to

```
=$B$2#
```

The hash symbol is the syntax if the whole spill range should be used.

[image]

And the drop-down in action. No VBA. Just formulas. (Note that the data source, the Unique() function and the data validation cells can all be on different worksheets.

[image]

Comment: Hi Teylyn, i dont have access to unique function as of now. also, the sheet being prepared will be used by people who will be working on older versions of excel, so i would prefer not using unique. kindly let me know if you have any other option available.

Comment: There are many, many sources on the internet that describe how to get unique values from a list. Which approach did you use and where are you stuck? Show your own effort and the we can help you with that.