# How to remove duplicates in array in VBA and concatenate them

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an array an VBA
strname=[English,science,Social,English,Social,science,science,Social,English,,,]

I want to remove duplicates and empty values in this array and concatenate them.
*Expected Output : English;science;Social*

I tried with looping logic but it doesnt work

```
For i=0 to 10
 if strname[i] <> "" then
   if strname[i]= strname[i+1] then 
       tempstr=strname[i]
   end i
 end if
next
```

here it will check 0 with 1 , 1 with 2 like that.Am trying for proper solution

Comment: Have you done any research? There are many examples eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array

Comment: You may wish to read up on the Scripting.Dictionary object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub removeArrDuplAndEmpty()
   Dim x As String, arr, i As Long, dict As Object
   
   x = "English,science,Social,English,Social,science,science,Social,English,,,"
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   arr = Split(x, ",") 'extract the array
   
   For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) <> "" Then dict(arr(i)) = 1 'create unique keys for non blank array elements
   Next 

   arr = dict.keys 'place back the dictionary keys in the initial array
   Debug.Print Join(arr, ";") 'only to visually see the result
End Sub
```

The next version processes the string as you show it in your question:

```
Sub removeArrDuplAndEmptyBis()
   Dim x As String, arr, i As Long, dict As Object
   
   x = "[English,science,Social,English,Social,science,science,Social,English,,,]"
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   arr = Split(left(Mid(x, 2), Len(Mid(x, 2)) - 1), ",")
   
   For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) <> "" Then dict(arr(i)) = 1
   Next i
   arr = dict.keys
   Debug.Print Join(arr, ",")
End Sub
```

This is what you want?
If not, please show an example of **your real string** and **how it must look** after processing...

Comment: Why X was declared in "".I am getting values in [ ] ....not in "" It will work only when we declare value as dict

Comment: @Yes_par_row I cannot get you... 1. Do you have a string or an array? I used a string (exactly what you show in your question), to split it in an array and iterate/work by array elements. Is your string to be processed between `[` `]` characters? Do you want it returned also between these characters? Please, better explain how **exactly** your string to be processed looks and how **exactly** to be returned.

Comment: @Yes_par_row Please, test the second version and send some feedback.

Comment: "ActiveX Component Can’t Create Object"-Am facing this error version : windows 10

Comment: @Yes_par_row This is not possible. Did it create the object in the first version and doesn't now? Do you have AnyDesk installed? If yes and you accept a connection, i would like to see what's happening in your environment. Did you test the sub **exactly as it is**?

Comment: Yes It was worked in local.When i run the exact code in client machine,it was throwing an error

Comment: @Yes_par_row Isn't it a MAC computer?

Comment: @Yes_par_row Can you add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'? Do yo see it between `Availalble References`?

Comment: @Yes_par_row May I connect to the respective computer?

Comment: @FaneDuru- It was resolved . I used below method to declare Dictionary.                                          DIM Dict as Scripting.Dictionary                                                                                                                                                                              Set Dict=New Scripting.Dictionary