# How do I sort within a cell - 2nd

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I have an excel sheet where 1 column contains various words in each cell. The words in each cell are seperated by a blankspace " ". Now I would like to sort the words within each cell alphabetically

*Example*

*Cell A1: "how can i sort this" => "can how i sort this"*

*Cell A2: "i dont know" => "dont i know"*

**What I tried**: I have found the following solution: [excel: how do i sort within a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399823/excel-how-do-i-sort-within-a-cell). The solution is for cells where text is separated by commas and I could not make it work in my case.

Any idea what I need to do to solve my sorting problem?

Comment: *"could not make it work"* Care to expand? Unless you specify this, then your question *is* a duplicate of [excel: how do i sort within a cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399823/excel-how-do-i-sort-within-a-cell) and should be closed.

Answer (score -1):

Take the value of the cell and then use string manipulation within VBA. After you have finished with that, make the cell equal to the new string.