# How to Open a FTP file with a * wild character in Name Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to open a file from a folder in FTP Site.
This folder has multiple reports with the same name only difference is timestamp i.e. Reports for each day

So i was trying to use a Wild Character * in my code to pick up todays report , see the code below

```
sReportDate = Format(ReportDate, "mmddyy")
ReportName = "_______Notification_of_Separation_______.POSFTPADPRFT1JFAGP02." &   sReportDate  & "*.csv" 

Workbooks.OpenText fileName:="ftp://UserID:Password@IPAddress/Separation Notifications/" & ReportName
```

but it is not working and doesn't opens the file.

however if i hard code the report name it works, there is some thing wrong with wild character.

Any help ??

Comment: What if there were two matching files - which one would you expect to open?

Comment: I tried something similar long long time ago in VB6 using the API `FtpFindFirstFile` to get the complete file name and path using wild cards. Unfortunately since I don't have access to a FTP site so I can't test it. You might want to search google on `FtpFindFirstFile API`? Once you have the complete file name and path you can then open that in Excel...

Comment: @Tim : There will one file for each day with the date and time at the end , there isn't any doubt on that

Comment: @Swapnil - you might know that, but Excel doesn't (what would happen if there __were__ multiple matches?) If you want to determine the exact name of the file you want, you'll have to run a directory listing on the folder and use the name of the file which matches your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

From Excel VBA Help:

> ***FileName***  Required **String**.  The file name of the workbook to be opened

Names of individual files on Windows systems (and I guess you are running Excel under Windows) cannot contain wildcard characters. You must specify the exact filename of the file you want to open.

Since you say all the files in the directory have "the same name only difference is timestamp", and you are providing that in `sReportDate`, why is the wildcard needed anyway?

If in fact the filename has a *variable* timestamp after the date, then you will need to interrogate the folder to find the relevant file to open. There's a start with doing that in another question: [Does Dir() make any guarantee on the order of files returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282940/does-dir-make-any-guarantee-on-the-order-of-files-returned) You **can** use wildcards when you are examining filenames in a directory — then, having found one which matches your date, you know the relevant name and can open it explicitly.

Comment: along with the date file name time it took to complete and there is no way to know that how much time it took to complete hence i am using wild card after date.

Comment: Any Idea about how to implement dir() search for the file on FTP ?