# Not able to merge many Word docs in right order to one using Macros?

Tags: vba, merge, ms-word

I am trying to merge many word documents into one word document using VBA Macros. I wrote the following code to do this task

```
Sub MergeDocs()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim MainDoc As Document
    Dim strFile As String, strFolder As String
    Dim Count As Long
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Pick your folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show Then
            strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    Set MainDoc = Documents.Add
    strFile = Dir$(strFolder & "*.doc") '
    Count = 0
    Do Until strFile = ""
        Count = Count + 1
        Set rng = MainDoc.Range
        With rng
            .Collapse 0
            If Count > 1 Then
                .InsertBreak 2
                .End = MainDoc.Range.End
                .Collapse 0
            End If
            .InsertFile strFolder & strFile
        End With
        strFile = Dir$()
    Loop
    MsgBox ("Files are merged")
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
```

This does it's job very well except the order of the docs is not in correct way.

So here is the example how it's working.
If i merge the docs as doc1,doc2,doc3,doc4 into one doc, then this macro merges them all but in random order as doc3,doc2,doc4,doc1 where as i want the docs to be in order as doc1,doc2,doc3,doc4.

Could anyone please try it and help me to get this resolved as i am not having much exposure on VB Macros in MS-Word.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282940/does-dir-make-any-guarantee-on-the-order-of-files-returned

Comment: Thanks munircontractor. It helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution to my problem and posting my code here for the people facing similar issue

```
Sub MergeDocs()
```

'   Macro for Merging of Many Word Documents into a Single one'

```
'   Variable Declaration'
Dim rng As Range
Dim MainDoc As Document
Dim AllDocs As Variant
Dim strFile As String, strFolder As String
Dim Count As Long

'   Assigning a value for further use in loop'
Count = 1

'   Ask User to select the Folder containing word documents to be merged'
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Pick the To_Be_Merged Documents Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show Then
        strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

Set MainDoc = Documents.Add

'   Calling GetFileList Function  to get all the documents from folder selected'
AllDocs = GetFileList(strFolder & "*.doc")

'   Calling QuickSort Subroutine to sort the array in ascending order'
If IsArray(AllDocs) Then
    Call QuickSort(AllDocs, LBound(AllDocs), UBound(AllDocs))
End If

Select Case IsArray(AllDocs)

    Case True
        MsgBox UBound(AllDocs) & " documents found"
        For Index = LBound(AllDocs) To UBound(AllDocs)
            strFile = AllDocs(Index)
            Count = Count + 1
            Set rng = MainDoc.Range
            With rng
                .Collapse 0
                If Count > 2 Then
                    .InsertBreak 2
                    .End = MainDoc.Range.End
                    .Collapse 0
                End If
                    .InsertFile strFolder & strFile
            End With
        Next Index

    Case False
        MsgBox "No File Found"

End Select
    MsgBox ("Your documents have been merged successfully")

lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

'  Returns an array of filenames that match FileSpec'

```
Function GetFileList(FileSpec As String) As Variant

'   Variables declaration'
Dim FileArray() As Variant
Dim FileCount As Integer
Dim FileName As String

On Error GoTo NoFilesFound

FileCount = 0
FileName = Dir(FileSpec)
If FileName = "" Then GoTo NoFilesFound

'   Loop until no more matching files are found
Do While FileName <> ""
    FileCount = FileCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To FileCount)
    FileArray(FileCount) = FileName
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
GetFileList = FileArray
Exit Function

'   Error handler

NoFilesFound:
GetFileList = False
End Function
```

'   Returns array sorted in ascending order'

```
Sub QuickSort(vArray As Variant, inLow As Long, inHi As Long)
```

'   Variables declaration'

```
Dim pivot   As Variant
Dim tmpSwap As Variant
Dim tmpLow  As Long
Dim tmpHi   As Long

tmpLow = inLow
tmpHi = inHi

pivot = vArray((inLow + inHi) \ 2)

While (tmpLow <= tmpHi)

    While (vArray(tmpLow) < pivot And tmpLow < inHi)
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
    Wend

    While (pivot < vArray(tmpHi) And tmpHi > inLow)
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
    Wend

    If (tmpLow <= tmpHi) Then
        tmpSwap = vArray(tmpLow)
        vArray(tmpLow) = vArray(tmpHi)
        vArray(tmpHi) = tmpSwap
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
    End If

Wend

If (inLow < tmpHi) Then QuickSort vArray, inLow, tmpHi
If (tmpLow < inHi) Then QuickSort vArray, tmpLow, inHi

lbl_Exit:
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Thanks