# How to add a number to a name of a copied worksheet in a new workbook in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have files named "A0118", "A0218"..."A1208". Each file has different number of sheets but they have same names. e.g. "A0118" has  worksheets names "1", "2", "3", "X" "Y"; "A1218" has worksheets "1", "3", "Y".

I want to copy all the worksheets from each file into a new workbook and have the names of the worksheet include the name of the file so for file "A0118" i want the copied sheets to be named "0118 - 1" so add "0118 - " in front of the original sheet name.

I'm not sure how to amend the copied worksheet and I'm stuck at this line

```
ActiveSheet.Name = "0118 - " &
```

Any help would be much appriciated. Thanks
Any advice on improving the existing code is also appriciated!

```
Sub XYZ()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False  


Dim sh As Worksheet



Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\CopyHere.xlsx"
    Set b1 = ActiveWorkbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\A0118.xlsx", Password:="1", writeresPassword:="1"
    Set b2 = ActiveWorkbook

For Each sh In b2.Sheets
    sh.Copy After:=b1.Sheets(b1.Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "0118 - " &
Next sh
Workbooks("A0118.xlsx").Close


' 
'
'
    
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\A1218.xls", Password:="1", writeresPassword:="1"
    Set b13 = ActiveWorkbook
For Each sh In b13.Sheets
    sh.Copy After:=b1.Sheets(b1.Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "1218 - " &
Next sh
Workbooks("A1218.xlsx").Close
 


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need the file name to be variable, you have to loop through the files in the folder and reference them when you're assigning the sheet's names.

I put together this code (credits to thespreadsheetguru) that should be useful to learn about the process.

**Some suggestions:**

- Name your procedure and variables to something meaningful
- Indent your code (you may use [www.rubberduckvba.com](https://www.rubberduckvba.com))
- Split the logic in steps

Read the code's comments and step into it using `F8` key

Adjust it with your file paths

---

**Code:**

```
Public Sub RenameAndCopySheets()
    ' Credits: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/23/loop-through-all-excel-files-in-a-given-folder
    ' Modified by: www.ricardodiaz.co

    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    
    ' Turn off stuff
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    ' Set destination workbook
    Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook
    Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(fileName:="C:\Temp\SampleExcelFiles\CopyHere.xlsx")
    
    ' Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
    Dim fileExtension As String
    fileExtension = "*.xls*"
    
    Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = "C:\Temp\SampleExcelFiles\"
    
    ' Target Path with Ending Extension
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = Dir(folderPath & fileExtension)
    
    ' Loop through each Excel file in folder
    Do While fileName <> ""
    
        ' Skip destination file
        If fileName <> destinationWorkbook.Name Then
        
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=folderPath & fileName, Password:="1", writeresPassword:="1")
        
        'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents
        
        ' Loop through each sheet
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        For Each sourceSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
            
            ' Copy sheet at the end
            sourceSheet.Copy After:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(destinationWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
            
            ' Rename sheet copied (be aware that you don't have hidden sheets otherwise this process could fail)
            destinationWorkbook.Sheets(destinationWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Name = Mid(fileName, 2, 4) & " - " & sourceSheet.Name
        
        Next sourceSheet
        
        'Save and Close Workbook
        sourceWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
        'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents
        
        End If
        
        'Get next file name
        fileName = Dir
    Loop
    
CleanExit:
        ' Turn on stuff again
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Exit Sub
    
CleanFail:
        MsgBox "An error occurred:" & Err.Description
        GoTo CleanExit
    
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you! it worked almost perfectly:
1. 
'code' destinationWorkbook.Sheets(destinationWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Name = Mid(fileName, 2, 4) & " - " & sourceSheet.Name

this creates an extension after the 4th letter, so the new name is "0118.xls - Name", is there a way to remove the file extension in the name? Not very important, just a preference and easier on the eye

2. it doesn't go through the files in any particular order. Is there a way to make it go in order? 
start with "A0118" -> "A0218" -> .....-> "A0318"

Comment: 1) For the file name use the left or len functions. 2) To sort the dir results, check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/4282940/1521579

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim i As Integer
For Each sh In b2.Sheets
    i = 1
    sh.Copy After:=b1.Sheets(b1.Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "0118 - " & b2.Sheets(i).Name
    i = i + 1
Next sh
```

Comment: Why do you need `i`? Isn't `b2.Sheets(i)` the same as `sh` or am I missing something?

Comment: sh is a sheet, but i is a number,