# Sort 2D array in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sorting, multidimensional-array

Good day,

I am trying to sort a 2D array, based on the contents of the first column. I found this code for "QuickSortArray" which seem to be the solution:

[Sorting a multidimensionnal array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873182/sorting-a-multidimensionnal-array-in-vba)

Although I can't make it work for my example. My example is:

```
Sub test()

Dim TestArray1(1 To 4, 0 To 1) As Variant
Dim TestArray2

TestArray1(1, 0) = 108
TestArray1(2, 0) = 109
TestArray1(3, 0) = 106
TestArray1(4, 0) = 110

TestArray1(1, 1) = 10
TestArray1(2, 1) = 5
TestArray1(3, 1) = 15
TestArray1(4, 1) = 2

TestArray2 = QuickSortArray(TestArray1, , , 2)

Debug.Print TestArray2(2, 1)

End Sub
```

I try to sort the array, based on the first or second column.

The error is:

> expecting function or variable.

Do you know what is wrong with my example?

Answer (score 2):

`QuickSortArray` is a Sub not a function and it cannot be assigned to variable like this:

```
TestArray2 = QuickSortArray(TestArray1, , , 2)
```

In order to make your code working you need to modify it like below:

```
Sub test()

    Dim TestArray1(1 To 4, 0 To 1) As Variant
    Dim TestArray2

    TestArray1(1, 0) = 108
    TestArray1(2, 0) = 109
    TestArray1(3, 0) = 106
    TestArray1(4, 0) = 110

    TestArray1(1, 1) = 10
    TestArray1(2, 1) = 5
    TestArray1(3, 1) = 15
    TestArray1(4, 1) = 2

    TestArray2 = TestArray1
    Call QuickSortArray(TestArray2, , , 2)

    Debug.Print TestArray2(2, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mielk! Regards Marcel