# Excel VBA calling Sub from Function, recursive Function, Array Function recalculation

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, recursion

I’m stuck, please help.  I have a small dynamic length array (6:20 x 2 text/numeric) and I want to automatically create a sorted copy so I can plot a monatonic scatter graph.  To recalculate automatically, I was thinking Function.   I plagiarised QuickSortArray, which works for the sorting as a Sub.

Q1: I can’t manage to call QuickSortArray from a Function even though I can successfully call it from another Sub.  The working Sub call is below.  I changed Sub QuickSortArray to Function QuickSortArray invoked from the spreadsheet, but could not get it to work.  As it does work from a Sub, can I trick CallSub into running when the data changes?  That makes the next two questions moot.

```
Sub CallSub()
   temparray = Range("weekdays")
   Call QuickSortArray(temparray, , , 2)
   Dim MyRange As String
   MyRange = "daysout"
   Range(MyRange) = temparray
End Sub
```

Q2: I notice that QuickSortArray is recursive (calls itself): can this work within a function?  The VBA I used is the top code here:
[Sorting a multidimensionnal array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873182/sorting-a-multidimensionnal-array-in-vba#5104206)  . At the bottom it has these recursive calls

```
If (lngMin < j) Then Call QuickSortArray(SortArray, lngMin, j, lngColumn)
If (i < lngMax) Then Call QuickSortArray(SortArray, i, lngMax, lngColumn)
```

Q3: The code below is the only working way I have found to pass an array and retrieve it.  Weekdays is a named range on the spreadsheet.  However, Fn SortDays does not automatically recalculate, either as a single cell function, or (as I want to) when using Array arithmetic to retrieve the whole array?  The function Test below it recalculates automatically and returns the results into an array of {=test($L$20)} in the spreadsheet ($L$20 = x).  So it is not recalculation settings.

```
Function SortDays() As Variant  
Dim InputArray As Variant 
InputArray = Range("weekdays")  
SortDays = InputArray  
End Function  

Function Test(x As Integer) As Variant
    Dim V() As Variant
    Dim N As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim C As Long
    ReDim V(1 To 3, 1 To 4)
    For R = 1 To 3
        For C = 1 To 4
            N = N * x + 1
            V(R, C) = N
        Next C
    Next R
    Test = V
End Function
```

Comment: 1) Yes subs and functions can call each other.  2) In the example it is not recursive.  The line `SortDays = InputArray` does not call `Sortdays`, it sets the return value. 3) Not sure I understand this part.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Where are your `QuickSortSub`, the function failed calling, and the sub succeed calling? Maybe a prefix `Public` before `QuickSortSub` can solve it.

Comment: Help us to help you; **post your current code**.