# VBA sort Two-digit array

Tags: vba, sorting

I want to sort below Two-digit array by VBA code

```
A 1
B 2
A 1
C 3
```

or below:

```
1 A
2 B
1 A
3 C
```

I have tried to sort them by Dictionary, but, Dictionary is not allowed to insert duplate key.

Is there any want to sort above array by number 1,2,3

Comment: What kind of array? How have you declared it? Does this asnwer your question: [Sorting a multidimensionnal array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873182/sorting-a-multidimensionnal-array-in-vba)

Comment: @MaciejLos I have not declared, I just have such data, I want to order them, and I think I need array. If there is any way to achieve without array, that's ok.

Comment: You can use [Range.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort) method.

Comment: I want to achieve by vba without excel object. @MaciejLos

Comment: Take a look at my first comment. There's a link to similar question and they say that the best way (the easiest one)  is to use Excel sheet. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I made this some time ago, it might help.

```
Function ArraySorter(ByVal RecArray As Variant, Optional ByVal RefCol As Integer = 0) As Variant
Dim Menor As String
Dim NewArray() As Variant
Dim i As Double, j As Double
Dim menorIndex As Double
Dim NewArrayIndex() As Double
Dim UsedIndex() As Double
ReDim NewArrayIndex(UBound(RecArray, 2))
ReDim NewArray(UBound(RecArray), UBound(RecArray, 2))
For i = 0 To UBound(NewArrayIndex)
    NewArrayIndex(i) = -1
Next i
UsedIndex = NewArrayIndex
For i = 0 To UBound(RecArray, 2)
    Menor = ""
    menorIndex = -1
    For j = 0 To UBound(RecArray, 2)
        If UsedIndex(j) = -1 Then
            If Menor = "" Then
                Menor = RecArray(RefCol, j)
                menorIndex = j
            Else
                If RecArray(RefCol, j) < Menor Then
                    Menor = RecArray(RefCol, j)
                    menorIndex = j
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
    UsedIndex(menorIndex) = 1
    NewArrayIndex(i) = menorIndex
Next i
For i = 0 To UBound(NewArrayIndex)
    For j = 0 To UBound(NewArray)
        NewArray(j, i) = RecArray(j, NewArrayIndex(i))
    Next j
Next i
ArraySorter = NewArray
End Function
```

If you have something like:

```
Function testArraySorter()
Dim myArr() As Variant

ReDim myArr(1, 3)

myArr(0, 0) = "A"
myArr(0, 1) = "B"
myArr(0, 2) = "A"
myArr(0, 3) = "C"

myArr(1, 0) = 1
myArr(1, 1) = 2
myArr(1, 2) = 1
myArr(1, 3) = 3

myArr = ArraySorter(myArr)

For i = 0 To UBound(myArr, 2)
    Debug.Print myArr(0, i), myArr(1, i)
Next i

End Function
```

you'll get this in your immediate verification :

```
A 1 
A 1 
B 2 
C 3
```

If you need to sort based in two or more columns, you could add a dummy column into your array, concatenate the criteria columns into it and then set this dummy column as RefCol: myArr = ArraySorter(myArr, addedColNumberHere).

Hope this helps.