# Excel VBA Generating a random number in order and according to how many

Tags: excel, vba, random, formula, sorting

G'day,

I have a tricky problem with getting random numbers in sorted order according  to how many I need by either VBA code or formula within VBA. This need is generated randomly between 1 and 10.

It looks something like this when it starts.

[image]

and here is the effect I had in mind where it shows sorted numbers according to how many failed in the example.

[image]

This is one attempt by VBA I did where cell J7 contains the random of how many I need but the numbers not quite sorted. I'm open to suggestions/feedback here. Many thanks.

```
Public Const BeCoolMachineCounter As String = "J7"
Public Const BeCoolMachineRange As String = "Q03:Q12"
'Generate the random data according to how many needed.
Call CreateNumbers(Range(BeCoolMachineRange), Range(BeCoolMachineCounter).Value)
Private Sub CreateNumbers(Which As Range, HowMany As Integer)
' Declaration of variables
    Dim c As Range
    Dim iCheck As Long

    iCheck = 1

' Generate random failures based on the number of required for each supplier
    For Each c In Which
        If iCheck <= HowMany Then
            c.Value = Random1to2192
            iCheck = iCheck + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: If the spreadsheet layout is static, I'd try `SMALL` worksheet function.

Comment: Hi Juri, I don't think SMALL worksheet function is required here as this implies one number. Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: `=SMALL($B$3:$B$12),ROW()-2` copied down from C3 into cells `C3:C12`of your example sorts all your output data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array formula in the destination range and a UDF returning the array.

It gives you exactly the result you're showing.

So, the UDF :

```
Public Function GetRandomFailures(count As Long) As Variant
    Dim result As Variant, numbers As Variant
    ReDim result(100)
    ReDim numbers(count - 1)

    For i = 0 To count - 1
        numbers(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)
    Next i

    Call QuickSort(numbers, LBound(numbers), UBound(numbers))

    For i = 0 To 99
        If i < count Then
            result(i) = numbers(i)
        Else
            result(i) = ""
        End If
    Next i

    GetRandomFailures = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(result)
End Function

Public Sub QuickSort(vArray As Variant, inLow As Long, inHi As Long)

  Dim pivot   As Variant
  Dim tmpSwap As Variant
  Dim tmpLow  As Long
  Dim tmpHi   As Long

  tmpLow = inLow
  tmpHi = inHi

  pivot = vArray((inLow + inHi) \ 2)

  While (tmpLow <= tmpHi)

     While (vArray(tmpLow) < pivot And tmpLow < inHi)
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
     Wend

     While (pivot < vArray(tmpHi) And tmpHi > inLow)
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
     Wend

     If (tmpLow <= tmpHi) Then
        tmpSwap = vArray(tmpLow)
        vArray(tmpLow) = vArray(tmpHi)
        vArray(tmpHi) = tmpSwap
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
     End If

  Wend

  If (inLow < tmpHi) Then QuickSort vArray, inLow, tmpHi
  If (tmpLow < inHi) Then QuickSort vArray, tmpLow, inHi

End Sub
```

and a sample formula :

```
{=GetRandomFailures(A1)}
```

(braces added by Excel)

You can of course simply call this UDF from a macro but IMHO using an array-formula could improve the user experience as all is transparent and the list is refreshed each time you change the count.

Note : the quick-sort implementation is from here : [VBA array sort function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function)

Comment: thanks for suggesting. I'll review the code and let you know.

Comment: thanks Serious, it works as I wanted. This has solved my problem once I remembered how to do the CSE formulas.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you've said, but based on the Before and After I've assumed you already have the 10 numbers in the column and you want to get a random sample of size *HowMany* from them and then make sure the numbers taken are then sorted in order.

```
Public Sub RandomSample(Data10 As Range, HowMany As Integer)

    ' Insert random numbers next to the data
    Data10.Cells(1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=RAND()"
    Data10.Cells(1, 2).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Data10.Cells(1, 2), Data10.Cells(10, 2))

    ' Sort the data by the random numbers
    Range(Data10.Cells(1, 1), Data10.Cells(10, 2)).Sort key1:=Data10.Cells(1, 2), header:=xlNo
    ' Remove the random numbers
    Range(Data10.Cells(1, 2), Data10.Cells(10, 2)).ClearContents

    ' Remove numbers surplus to HowMany
    If HowMany < 10 Then
        Range(Data10.Cells(HowMany + 1, 1), Data10.Cells(10, 1)).ClearContents
    End If

    ' Resort the remaining numbers
    Range(Data10.Cells(1, 1), Data10.Cells(HowMany, 1)).Sort key1:=Data10.Cells(1, 1), header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

You can call this with **RandomSample Range("B3:B12"),6**

Comment: Hi Morbo, Yes that is correct, 10 numbers and in sorted order. I used 10 numbers in the static pictures I provided as a small sample for illustrative purposes. I'll have a look at what this code does and see if this fits to what I had in mind. Thanks.

Comment: I had a go with this code and I believe the sorting is not working as it clears the data once populated.

Comment: It worked for me in Excel 2003 as I have described in the comments. If you want 3 numbers it WILL delete the remaining 7 numbers.