# QuickSort on a LinkedList in VBA

Tags: vba, linked-list, quicksort

I've unfortunately inherited some VBA code which uses LinkedLists in VBA but nothing is sorted, and needs to be sorted.

LinkedList example:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/166394

I'm trying to do a quicksort on the items by translating the following code to a LinkedList:
[VBA array sort function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function)

But I'm having a hard time following the logic of the function to determine how to translate it to a non-numbered system like a Linked List.

Could someone help comment up the code to explain what is happening, or possibly help in the translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need a Linked List object. I will use an array for the example. Let's take 5 nodes for the simplicity of the example.

```
'Declaration of the array
Dim LinkedList(0 To 4) As Node
```

Now, time to fill the array. We say that the variable `head` is the head of our `LinkedList` :

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

Dim currentNode As Node
Set currentNode = head.pnext

While Not currentNode.pnext Is currentNode 'walk rest of list to end
    LinkedList(i) = currentNode
    i = i + 1
    Set currentNode = currentNode.pnext      'current pointer to next node
Wend
```

Our `LinkedList` is now filled, we can use the **Quicksort**. We launch the initial call with this line :

```
QuickSort LinkedList, LBound(LinkedList), UBound(LinkedList)
```

And we adapt a little the function :

```
Public Sub QuickSort(vArray As Node, inLow As Long, inHi As Long)

  Dim pivot   As Integer
  Dim tmpSwap As Integer
  Dim tmpLow  As Long
  Dim tmpHi   As Long

  tmpLow = inLow
  tmpHi = inHi

  pivot = vArray((inLow + inHi) \ 2).Key

  While (tmpLow <= tmpHi)

     While (vArray(tmpLow).Key < pivot And tmpLow < inHi)
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
     Wend

     While (pivot < vArray(tmpHi).Key And tmpHi > inLow)
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
     Wend

     If (tmpLow <= tmpHi) Then
        tmpSwap = vArray(tmpLow).Key
        vArray(tmpLow).Key = vArray(tmpHi).Key
        vArray(tmpHi).Key = tmpSwap
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
     End If

  Wend

  If (inLow < tmpHi) Then QuickSort vArray, inLow, tmpHi
  If (tmpLow < inHi) Then QuickSort vArray, tmpLow, inHi

End Sub
```

I think it's good. Tell me if there is a problem or a misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept this answer. I don't know how I missed this had been answered.