# Sorting 2 dimensional variant array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA (I wish I could stick to Javascript) and I have a problem with sorting an array.
I have this 2 dimensional array in keeping track of player scores like this

```
P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9
23 12 34 11 21 56 32 35 27
```

And I would like to sort the array so the players are in order of scores from lowest to highest like this

```
P4 P2 P5 P1 P9 P7 P3 P8 P6
11 12 21 23 27 32 34 35 56
```

I haven't got a clue how to do this in VBA. I tried looking for a sort function, to no avail. Do I need to include some library or something?

Does anyone know how to tackle this problem if a library isn't available to do this?

Regards
Crouz

Comment: [This should get you started](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx), it outlines two options.

Comment: The linked QuickSort answers are easily adaptable to a 2D array.  If you get stuck with the adaptation, ask a better quality Q abot that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your data in **A1** through **I2**:

and then run this macro:

```
Sub Macro4()
    Range("A1:I2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:I2"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:I2")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

This is right from the Macro Recorder.

Comment: thanks for the info. I shall use the Macro recorder in the future, it's a gem.

Answer (score -1):

I checked, and sure enough, some of the SO champs had already put together QuickSort routines in VBA.  Here's a link:

[VBA array sort function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function)