# Excel VBA sort string macro

Tags: excel, string, vba, sorting

I have a word in each row that I want to sort. It does not matter which of the words comes first as long as they are sorted. Below is an example of my excel sheet where I have replaced the word with one single letter instead. Is it possible to write a macro to help me to sort?

Thanks in advance!

Column 1

x

y

x

z

x

y

Comment: look here:http://stackoverflow.com/q/152319/382588

Comment: start recording a Macro, do your sorting with excel (Data-> Sort) and when you're done stop the macro. Finally open VEB editor (ALT+F11) and see the code

Answer (score 1):

use below line

```
Range("A1").Sort key1:=Range("A1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```