# How to identify the indices for the nth smallest values in a multi dimensional array in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a 3 dimensional array full of different values. I would like to find the indices corresponding to the "nth" smallest values in the array. For example... If the 3 smallest values were 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3 I would like to see, in order, the indices for these values. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ...and the code you've tried??

Comment: and the format of the indices?

Comment: I don't have any code for this yet because I dont know where to even start. I would like to create a new array that has the indices. So if 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3 were located at A(1,3,6), A(2, 4, 7) and A(3, 4,5) I would like to get an array that looks like this: [[ 1, 3, 6 ][ 2, 4, 7 ][ 3, 4, 5 ]]

Comment: Would it help if I posted the code so far?

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830532/find-the-indices-for-the-minimum-values-in-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-vba?noredirect=1#comment76643767_44830532

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to approach this would be adding an original index dimension into your 3rd array, then sorting, by the current values to find out the smallest item and returning the original index. Take a look into this: [VBA array sort function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function)