# Telling VBA to look at 64-bit registry view

Tags: vba, excel, winapi, registry, clsid

I want to assign an `ArrayList` to a variable.

```
Sub Create_ArrayList()
    Dim arrL As Object

    'Creating an ArrayList, option 1 - fails
    Set arrL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    'Creating an ArrayList, option 2 - fails
    Set arrL = GetObject("New:{6896B49D-7AFB-34DC-934E-5ADD38EEEE39}")
End Sub
```

Both options fail :

> Run-time error '-2146232576 (80131700)':
>   Automation error

I found that the CLSID exists in the registry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID`

[image: CLSID registry system.collections.arraylist]

The Office is 32-bit and Windows is 64-bit. I am not familiar with the registry, but it seems from what I have read, that 32-bit Office is trying to find ArrayList in some 32-bit Windows location (view), while it actually is in 64-bit location. Can it be the case? How to make the application get ArrayList from the correct location?

It seems, to access an [alternative registry view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view), I should somehow use the flag KEY_WOW64_64KEY (value 0x0100), but the examples that I found are too big to comprehend ([eg1](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?705261-access-64-bit-registry-from-32-bit-app#post_4893505), [eg2](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?796771-RESOLVED-Help!-cannot-delete-registry-x64-subkeys&p=4885513&viewfull=1#post_4885513)). I don't want to edit registry data, I only want to tell VBA that I am using 64-bit Windows, so the object that I need is to be found somewhere else than it expects.

Comment: Based on this link, I'd try installing the .Net 2 SP2 framework: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9bfcd001-5168-4cff-b2ba-6b8e8d465138/excel-2010-vb-runtime-error-2146232576-80131700-automation-error-on?forum=exceldev

Comment: you must have .Net framework installed indeed.

Comment: Looking at the 64 bit view won't help because your 32 bit process needs a 32 bit inproc server. Then again, do you really need to use a .net ArrayList to solve your problem? Why not code it in pure VBA?

Comment: I saw that page where it says that .Net framework is needed. But after seeing `System.Collections.ArrayList` in registry, I thought that it should work.. how did it get there, if it does not exist? Or it exists, but I just can't reach it without .Net framework?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I often find myself performance-oriented. This option seems promising performance-wise, because it naturally has `.Sort` method, so I would not need to write VBA array sorting function, which I have already reviewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function). But again, if .Net framework is needed, I would not be able to distribute the file to others so that I'm guaranteed it would work there.