# VBA multiple values from drop down in excel removing items selected in error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code which I am using which was written by Sumit Bansal which is working as I need it to

```
Dim Oldvalue As String

Dim Newvalue As String

Application.EnableEvents = True

On Error GoTo Exitsub

If Target.Address = "$D$26" Or Target.Address = "$D$38" Or Target.Address = "$C$4" Then

  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then

    GoTo Exitsub

  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Newvalue = Target.Value

    Application.Undo

    Oldvalue = Target.Value

      If Oldvalue = "" Then

        Target.Value = Newvalue

      Else

        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then

            Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue

      Else:

        Target.Value = Oldvalue

      End If

    End If

  End If

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

Exitsub:

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

However I have tried to amend the code to allow the user to remove a value if it has been selected in error, i.e. if they select
1
2
3

these appear in the cell on separate lines.

However 2 should not have been selected and needs to be removed so what appears in the cell is
1
3
and to appear on separate lines, not separated by a comma

The order of the selections should be the same as in the drop down list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901667/sort-data-validation-dropdown-list-within-cell/51903770#51903770

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort Data Validation dropdown list within cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901667/sort-data-validation-dropdown-list-within-cell)