# Order files in a list

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to list all files in a folder, but order isn't correct. I have file1, file2 to file15. Unfortunately file10 will be listed before file2. I have no influance on the names of the files, but I have to sort them like file1, file2 ... file9, file10 and so on.

```
Sub orderFiles()
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fld As Scripting.Folder
    Dim strWert As Variant

    Dim n As Long
    Dim arrNames() As String
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim TempTxt1 As String
    Dim TempTxt2 As String


    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    ' Modify as needed
    strFolder = p_PR1ImportPath & "\PR1\importiert"
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strFolder)

    ' Set up arrays
    n = fld.Files.Count
    ReDim arrNames(1 To n)

    ' Fill arrays
    For Each fil In fld.Files
        i = i + 1
        arrNames(i) = fil.Name
    Next fil

    'Alphabetize Sheet Names in Array List
      For x = LBound(arrNames) To UBound(arrNames)
        For y = x To UBound(arrNames)
          If UCase(arrNames(y)) < UCase(arrNames(x)) Then
            TempTxt1 = arrNames(x)
            TempTxt2 = arrNames(y)
            arrNames(x) = TempTxt2
            arrNames(y) = TempTxt1
          End If
         Next y
      Next x

    ' Do something with the arrays, e.g.
    For i = 1 To n
        Debug.Print arrNames(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The result isn't changed. How can I sort the list of files?

Comment: I did a simple workaround and renamed the file with `Name uo.Path & "\" & currentName As uo.Path & "\" & "File" & Format(Replace(Split(File, "File")(1), ".txt", ""), "00") & ".txt"` which isn't the best solution, but it works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe save file names to a table with number part extracted to a separate field. Use a query to sort. What is purpose of saving to an array just for Debug.Print?

Comment: Debug.Print is only for this demo. I will use arrNames(i) later on to load each file into Access. I don't prefer to create an extra table just to sort the list. In other languages like PHP you can easily sort array and with VBA it's seems really complicated :-( I prefer to rename the files instead of creating an extra table.Does anybody else has an idea how can I sort the array directly in VBA?

Comment: @HansUp: The files have always the same pattern with just a different number at the end and the extantion will be always .txt

Comment: Correct, sorting array in VBA is not simple. Your solution may be as good as any but review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function and https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2015/3/24/applying-an-alphabetical-sort-to-your-vba-array-list.

Answer (score 0):

I rename each file now with Format `"00"` like this:

```
' rename files
currentName = Dir(uo.Path & "\*.txt")
Do While Len(currentName) > 0
    desiredName = "file" & Format(Replace(Split(currentName, "file")(1), ".txt", ""), "00") & ".txt"
        If (currentName <> desiredName) Then
            Name uo.Path & "\" & currentName As uo.Path & "\" & desiredName
        End If
    currentName = Dir
Loop
```

This is just a workaround, but it works pretty well.