# Sort Range in absolute value

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I would like to sort a range in absolute value but keep the sign of the number.

I did a code that works fine, but I copy/paste values in another range and afterwards, I delete it.

I would like not to copy/paste in my sheet but just do it in memory.

How can I do that?

My range:

```
-1
2
3
-4
4.5
```

The expected result :

```
4.5
-4
3
2
-1
```

My code:

```
Sub Appel()

    For i = 1 To Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row
        Range("E" & i) = Abs(Range("D" & i).Value)
    Next i

    Range("E1", Range("D1").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=Range("E1"), 
    Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

    Columns("E:E").Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: You could use a custom sort: `Application.AddCustomList ListArray: SortArray`, where sort array has been created from the `abs(values)` in your list and is [sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in memory I would first load it to a single dimensional array.

Then I would create a specific function that does your custom sort on the array.

Once it's sorted, then simply set the value to that range from the sorted array.

```vb
Sub Appel()

    Dim TargetRange As Range
    Set TargetRange = Range("D1", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    'This returns as single dim array from a Range column
    Dim ColumnData As Variant
    ColumnData = Application.Transpose(TargetRange.Value)

    Dim SortedData As Variant
    SortedData = SortAbsoluteDecending(ColumnData)

    'Set value of range equal to the new sorted array.
    TargetRange.Value = Application.Transpose(SortedData)

End Sub
```

```vb
Public Function SortAbsoluteDecending(SourceArray As Variant) As Variant

    Dim OuterIndex As Long
    For OuterIndex = LBound(SourceArray) To UBound(SourceArray) - 1

        Dim InnerIndex As Long
        For InnerIndex = OuterIndex + 1 To UBound(SourceArray)

            If Abs(SourceArray(OuterIndex)) < Abs(SourceArray(InnerIndex)) Then
                Dim Temp As Variant
                Temp = SourceArray(InnerIndex)
                SourceArray(InnerIndex) = SourceArray(OuterIndex)
                SourceArray(OuterIndex) = Temp
            End If

        Next InnerIndex
    Next OuterIndex

    SortAbsoluteDecending = SourceArray

End Function
```