# filter unique values and sort A to Z Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using below code to Filter the Unique values from `Sheet1` and paste them into `Sheet2` my code is working fine.
But it has one issue that is when i remove any value from Sheet1.Range(C4:C) cell it gives empty cell in `Sheet2` like in below image.

I want that if i remove any cell value from Sheet1 range then Code should automatically adjust it. there should not be any empty cell in Sheet2 Range.

I also wants to add sort function in the code so unique values will be popup with sorting A to Z in sheet2.

I tried at my end to do both things but cannot do. Your help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim d As Object, c As Variant, i As Long, lr As Long
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c = Sheet1.Range("C4:C" & lr)
For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
  d(c(i, 1)) = 1
Next i
Sheet2.Range("C4").Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
End Sub
```

Comment: So you got a list of values in Sheet1(C4:C something) and want to paste them into Sheet2(C4:C something?

Comment: Yes you are right @Foxfire And Burns And Burns

Comment: You can take the values into array, then sort using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function) and then loop trough your array and paste it only if it's not blank

Comment: It is much difficult for me to convert this code first into arrays then  in loop @Foxfire And Burns And Burns like the link you provided. In arrays they dont have range and sheet name ?

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns  Ok set aside sorting thing how i can remove the blank cell using above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code I've used:

```
Sub test()
Dim WkSource As Worksheet
Dim WkDestiny As Worksheet
Dim MiMatriz() As Variant
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ZZ As Long

Set WkSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("source") 'Replace SOURCE with name of your Sheet1
Set WkDestiny = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("destiny") 'Replace DESTINY with name of your sheet2

With WkSource
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'Last non empty cell in colum C
    ReDim MiMatriz(1 To LR - 4 + 1) 'we do LR-4 because your data starts at row 4, and we add 1
    ZZ = 1
    For i = 4 To LR Step 1
        MiMatriz(ZZ) = .Range("C" & i).Value
        ZZ = ZZ + 1
    Next i
End With

'sort
Call QuickSort(MiMatriz, 1, UBound(MiMatriz))

'paste

'we paste array, excluding blanks
ZZ = 4 'starting at row 4
For i = 1 To UBound(MiMatriz) Step 1
    If MiMatriz(i) <> "" Then
        WkDestiny.Range("C" & ZZ).Value = MiMatriz(i)
        ZZ = ZZ + 1
    End If
Next i


'Remove duplicates
WkDestiny.Range("C4:C" & ZZ - 1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

Erase MiMatriz
Set WkSource = Nothing
Set WkDestiny = Nothing

End Sub
```

You'll need also this UDF to sort arrays:

```
Public Sub QuickSort(vArray As Variant, inLow As Long, inHi As Long)
  Dim pivot   As Variant
  Dim tmpSwap As Variant
  Dim tmpLow  As Long
  Dim tmpHi   As Long

  tmpLow = inLow
  tmpHi = inHi

  pivot = vArray((inLow + inHi) \ 2)

  While (tmpLow <= tmpHi)
     While (vArray(tmpLow) < pivot And tmpLow < inHi)
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
     Wend

     While (pivot < vArray(tmpHi) And tmpHi > inLow)
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
     Wend

     If (tmpLow <= tmpHi) Then
        tmpSwap = vArray(tmpLow)
        vArray(tmpLow) = vArray(tmpHi)
        vArray(tmpHi) = tmpSwap
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
     End If
  Wend

  If (inLow < tmpHi) Then QuickSort vArray, inLow, tmpHi
  If (tmpLow < inHi) Then QuickSort vArray, tmpLow, inHi
End Sub
```

My source sheet (your Sheet1) is:

[image]

And when executing code, in my destiny sheet (your sheet2) I get:

[image]

All data sorted and no blanks :)

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

about function to sort arrays, all credits go to author: https://stackoverflow.com/a/152325/9199828

Comment: ReDim MiMatriz(1 To LR - 4 + 1) script out of range error comes on this line @Foxfire And Burns thank you for helping out me

Comment: @Learning  `LR` according to your code, is the last non empty cell in column A. If it's raises an error, probably means LR is below 4. Change  `LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` to `LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row` and try. Or make sure column A got values

Comment: Yes i already changed it but data comes like this https://ibb.co/dPyWvwq  it does not remove the duplicates

Comment: @Learning I forgot about duplicates. Before line `Erase MiMatriz` just add `WkDestiny.Range("C4:C" & ZZ - 1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo`

Comment: Thank you for the help. You did great effort but its really really difficult for me to understand that how to understand these two codes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have O365, you can use a worksheet formula:

```
=UNIQUE(SORT(FILTER(Sheet10!$C$4:$C$10000,Sheet10!$C$4:$C$10000<>"")))
```

*Replace `Sheet1` with the actual name of your worksheet*

Another VBA method, using the ArrayList object:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rg As Range, c As Range
    Dim AL As Object, vData As Variant, v As Variant, I As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    
Set ws2 = Worksheets("sheet11") 'destination for paste operation
    
Set rg = Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
If Not Intersect(rg, Target) Is Nothing Then
    Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    vData = rg 'fastest to work from vba array
    For I = 1 To UBound(vData)
        v = vData(I, 1)
        If Not v = "" And Not AL.contains(v) Then
            AL.Add v
        End If
    Next I
    
    AL.Sort
    
    'If might have more than 65,535 items, cannot use Transpose
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ws2.Range("c4").Resize(Rows.Count - 4).ClearContents
    With ws2.Range("c4").Resize(AL.Count, 1)
        .Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AL.toarray)
        .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).ClearContents
    End With
    
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @Learning I added an alternate VBA method.  Don't know if it will work any better on your data.

Comment: Can you please have a look on my post where i mentioned the code with two sheets and ranges i tried to changed your accordingly but its not working @Ron Rosenfeld

Comment: @Learning assuming your code is on sheet one, you merely need to set WS2 equals sheet two.

Comment: I am unable to understand the thing that you have just updated single Sheet reference in your code. Where my code expresses that Sheet1 has data which will be filtered and paste into Sheet2 as unique values @Ron Rosenfeld.

Comment: @Learning if your worksheet code is on sheet one, there's no need to refer to it explicitly.

Comment: Never realized the power of `Contains`. Nice job. Thanks.

Comment: thank you @Ron Rosenfeld i got your point

Comment: Hi, I need your help with that code. @Ron I have been trying to use the same code. Which will get the range from Sheet3.rangeC4 to last used row and will paste sorted unique values into Sheet2.range(G4) i am unable to guess that how to select sheet3.

Please note that your above code is still being used in file and now i need to use it for Sheet3

Comment: What do you mean by *"use it for sheet 3"*?  The code goes on the sheet module for whatever sheet is your data source.  And the destination for the paste operation is set within the code.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Sorted Unique Column

- This solution uses a `Dictionary` for 'unique' and an `Array List` as a sorting option.
- In the current setup, as you change values in column `C` from cell `C4` of `Sheet1`, the unique values appear sorted in column `C` from cell `C4` of `Sheet2`.

**Standard Module (e.g. `Module1`)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copySortedUniqueColumn( _
        SourceRange As Range, _
        DestinationCell As Range, _
        Optional ByVal doSort As Boolean = True)
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    If SourceRange.Rows.Count > 1 Or SourceRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        Data = SourceRange.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = SourceRange.Value
    End If
    
    Dim arl As Object: Set arl = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            Key = Data(i, 1)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                    If Not .Exists(Key) Then
                        .Item(Key) = Empty
                        arl.Add Key
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        If .Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    End With
    
    If doSort Then
        arl.Sort
    End If
    
    ReDim Data(1 To arl.Count, 1 To 1)
    i = 0
    For Each Key In arl
        i = i + 1
        Data(i, 1) = Key
    Next Key
    
    With DestinationCell
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        .Resize(i).Value = Data
    End With

End Sub

Function defineColumnRange( _
    FirstCellRange As Range) _
As Range
    On Error GoTo clearError
    If FirstCellRange Is Nothing Then GoTo ProcExit
    With FirstCellRange
        Dim cel As Range: Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If cel Is Nothing Then GoTo ProcExit
        Set defineColumnRange = .Resize(cel.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

**Sheet Module (`Sheet1`)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const srcFirst As String = "C4"
    Const dstFirst As String = "C4"
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = defineColumnRange(Range(srcFirst))
    If srg Is Nothing Then
        With Sheet2.Range(dstFirst)
            .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Intersect(srg, Target)
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dCel As Range: Set dCel = Sheet2.Range(dstFirst)
    
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    copySortedUniqueColumn srg, dCel
SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub

clearError:
    Resume SafeExit

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you its working without any hesitation Thank you so much @VBasic2008

Comment: Hi, I need your help with that code. @VBasic2008 I have been trying to use the same code. Which will get the range from Sheet3.rangeC4 to last used row and will paste sorted unique values into Sheet2.range(G4) i am unable to guess that how to select sheet3.

Please note that your above code is still being used in file and now i need to use it for Sheet3

Comment: Copy the sheet module code (which you initially put in `Sheet1`) to the sheet module of `Sheet3` and change `dstFirst` to `G4`.