# How to use this code for for further sheets range (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using this below code to get the Unique sorted value from `Sheet1.Range("C4:C")` and to paste into `Sheet2.Range("C4")`. This is working fine

But now i want use the same code to get the Unique sorted value from `Sheet3.Range("C4:C")` and to paste into `Sheet2.Range("G4").`

now the problem is that how to mention the Sheet reference in code that which sheet range unique sorted value will be paste.

**Standard Module (e.g. Module1)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copySortedUniqueColumn( _
        SourceRange As Range, _
        DestinationCell As Range, _
        Optional ByVal doSort As Boolean = True)
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    If SourceRange.Rows.Count > 1 Or SourceRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        Data = SourceRange.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = SourceRange.Value
    End If
    
    Dim arl As Object: Set arl = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            Key = Data(i, 1)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                    If Not .Exists(Key) Then
                        .Item(Key) = Empty
                        arl.Add Key
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        If .Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    End With
    
    If doSort Then
        arl.Sort
    End If
    
    ReDim Data(1 To arl.Count, 1 To 1)
    i = 0
    For Each Key In arl
        i = i + 1
        Data(i, 1) = Key
    Next Key
    
    With DestinationCell
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        .Resize(i).Value = Data
    End With

End Sub

Function defineColumnRange( _
    FirstCellRange As Range) _
As Range
    On Error GoTo clearError
    If FirstCellRange Is Nothing Then GoTo ProcExit
    With FirstCellRange
        Dim cel As Range: Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If cel Is Nothing Then GoTo ProcExit
        Set defineColumnRange = .Resize(cel.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

**Sheet Module (Sheet1)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const srcFirst As String = "C4"
    Const dstFirst As String = "C4"
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = defineColumnRange(Range(srcFirst))
    If srg Is Nothing Then
        With Sheet2.Range(dstFirst)
            .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Intersect(srg, Target)
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dCel As Range: Set dCel = Sheet2.Range(dstFirst)
    
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    copySortedUniqueColumn srg, dCel
SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub

clearError:
    Resume SafeExit

End Sub
```

Comment: Where in your code do you use `Sub copySortedUniqueColumn`? If not used, why did you mentioned it in the question? If "you used it", how did you do it? Do you want using it in the event code you show us? If yes, why would will we be interested about all code and you do not show us your attempt to use it? if not, what are you trying accomplishing?

Comment: Here i used this in the code https://ibb.co/1bgvNYg. and i did not do this i got the help from StackOverFlow. I am just trying to do a simple thing that is posted code will get the unique and sorted values from the Sheet range and then paste it into different sheet range just.

Comment: @FaneDuru: You may have missed the use of `copySortedUniqueColumn` in the `Worksheet Change` event code.

Comment: @VBasic2008 This is what I also thought... And used page Find function, which counted only one occurrence. Even now, it counts three (plus two coming from both of us comments). He maybe edited the question, but I did not refresh the page. I will do it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do the following:

Copy the sheet module code (which you initially put in `Sheet1`) to the sheet module of `Sheet3` and change `dstFirst` to `G4`.

(This is a follow-up question on my answer to [*filter unique values and sort A to Z Excel VBA*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65900852/filter-unique-values-and-sort-a-to-z-excel-vba/65903169).)

Comment: Thank you @VBasic2008 its working Now. I was using both code instead of 2nd one for second sheet which was causing the problem.