# Is there a way to sort cell addresses?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

Is there a way to sort cell addresses from top left to bottom right?

e.g.

Dim targetAddress As String

targetAddress = "$E$12,$B$11:$C$12,$G$14,$F$2,$F9"  'randomly selected cells

I want to sort targetAddress from top left to bottom right as follows:

"$F$2,$F$9,$B$11:$C$12,$E$12,$G$14"

Comment: Yes, there is. What have you done to try so far? Where are you getting stuck? What can we help you with?

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you for your comment. I want to sort address(string) itself, not cells. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Does it change the result? Max(E11,B11) or Max(B11,E11)?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, it changes the result. I am implementing undo function using OnUndo to undo deleted cells back to a sheet. Because the addresses of deleted cells are not in order, I need to sort it before insert the cells.

Comment: @user19322791 - You should ask a question about undoing deletes - not this sorting of addresses.

Comment: How do you acquire this address? A range can have many ranges (cells) but its *Address* property can return only 255 characters. Are you aware of this limitation and will it conflict with whatever you're trying to do in the long run? I have done something similar related to the positions of shapes but have never seen a use of it elsewhere. It may be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), a case when you think there is no other way to do something but you don't want to reveal the big picture. Sharing what you're really trying to do would be more productive. It is a challenge though.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I take the address via argument of Workbook_SheetChange. 255 characters won't be a problem for my use. I will close this question.

Comment: @user19322791 - Don't close it. It's a good question if you can ask it in the right way.

Answer (score 2):

### Sorting the cell addresses of a union

My first thought was that a union is automatically sorted by Excel, but I was proven wrong. Here a proposal using Quicksort from user "jorge-ferreira".

**After rereading the question I found that the below

solution is NOT the answer which was searched for. ;-(**

```
Option Explicit

Sub sort_union()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim myArray(100) As String
    Dim iCt As Integer
    Dim maxCt As Long
    
    Set myRange = Union(Range("$E$12"), Range("$B$11:$C$12"), Range("$G$14"), Range("$F$2"), Range("$F9"))
    
    Debug.Print myRange.Address
    
    iCt = 0
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "ORIGINAL:"
    For Each myCell In myRange
        myArray(iCt) = myCell.Address
        Debug.Print iCt & " : " & myCell.Address & " =========> " & myArray(iCt)
        iCt = iCt + 1
    Next myCell
    maxCt = iCt - 1
    
    Call QuickSort(myArray, 0, maxCt)

    Set myRange = Nothing

    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "SORTED:"
    Set myRange = Range(myArray(0))
    Debug.Print 0, myArray(0)
    For iCt = 1 To maxCt
        Set myRange = Union(myRange, Range(myArray(iCt)))
        Debug.Print iCt, myArray(iCt)
    Next iCt

    Debug.Print vbCrLf & myRange.Address
End Sub

'using quicksort from
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function

Public Sub QuickSort(vArray As Variant, inLow As Long, inHi As Long)
  Dim pivot   As Variant
  Dim tmpSwap As Variant
  Dim tmpLow  As Long
  Dim tmpHi   As Long

  tmpLow = inLow
  tmpHi = inHi

  pivot = vArray((inLow + inHi) \ 2)

  While (tmpLow <= tmpHi)
     While (vArray(tmpLow) < pivot And tmpLow < inHi)
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
     Wend

     While (pivot < vArray(tmpHi) And tmpHi > inLow)
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
     Wend

     If (tmpLow <= tmpHi) Then
        tmpSwap = vArray(tmpLow)
        vArray(tmpLow) = vArray(tmpHi)
        vArray(tmpHi) = tmpSwap
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
     End If
  Wend

  If (inLow < tmpHi) Then QuickSort vArray, inLow, tmpHi
  If (tmpLow < inHi) Then QuickSort vArray, tmpLow, inHi
End Sub
```

Here the output of the Immediate Window:

```
$E$12,$B$11:$C$12,$G$14,$F$2,$F$9

ORIGINAL:
0 : $E$12 =========> $E$12
1 : $B$11 =========> $B$11
2 : $C$11 =========> $C$11
3 : $B$12 =========> $B$12
4 : $C$12 =========> $C$12
5 : $G$14 =========> $G$14
6 : $F$2 =========> $F$2
7 : $F$9 =========> $F$9

SORTED:
 0            $B$11
 1            $B$12
 2            $C$11
 3            $C$12
 4            $E$12
 5            $F$2
 6            $F$9
 7            $G$14

$B$11:$C$12,$E$12,$F$2,$F$9,$G$14
```

Answer (score 1):

### Sorting the cell addresses of a union with
ascending row and descending column

Finally the answer which was asked for! ;-)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Split_and_Sort()

    Dim myRangeStr As String
    Dim myRangeArr() As String
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim iCt As Integer
    Dim maxCt As Integer
    
    myRangeStr = "$E$12,$B$11:$C$12,$G$14,$F$2,$F9"
    myRangeArr = Split(myRangeStr, ",")
    
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "ORIGINAL:"
    Debug.Print myRangeStr & vbCrLf
    
    iCt = 1
    Range("A1") = "Address"
    Range("B1") = "Row"
    Range("C1") = "Column"
    
    For iCt = 0 To UBound(myRangeArr)
        If myRangeArr(iCt) <> "" Then
            'Debug.Print iCt; " "; myRangeArr(iCt)
            maxCt = iCt + 1
            
            Range("A1").Offset(iCt + 1, 0) = myRangeArr(iCt)
            Range("B1").Offset(iCt + 1, 0) = Range(myRangeArr(iCt)).Row
            Range("C1").Offset(iCt + 1, 0) = Range(myRangeArr(iCt)).Column
        End If
    Next iCt

    Call SortCurrentRegion
    
    Set myRange = Range(Range("A2").Value)
    'iCt = 1: Debug.Print: Debug.Print iCt; myRange.Address
    
    'create sorted union
    For iCt = 2 To maxCt
        Set myRange = Union(myRange, Range(Range("A1").Offset(iCt, 0)))
        Debug.Print iCt; myRange.Address
    Next iCt
    
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "SORTED:"
    Debug.Print myRange.Address

End Sub

Sub SortCurrentRegion()
    Dim sortRange As Range
    Set sortRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        
        'sort "Col B" = "Row" ascending
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    
        'sort "Col C" = "Column" descending
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    
        .SetRange Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Here the output of the Immediate Window:

```
ORIGINAL:
$E$12,$B$11:$C$12,$G$14,$F$2,$F9

SORTED:
$F$2,$F$9,$B$11:$C$12,$E$12,$G$14
```

Comment: In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72758907/timeline#comment_128517551) the OP says this part of an implementation of `OnUndo`.  I think writing to a sheet will mess with the Undo stack, so this method probably won't help here.  That said, you could rewrite to sort in memory

Answer (score 0):

### Sorting the cell addresses of a union with
ascending row and descending column

Straight forward approach using the inbuilt sort of Excel:

```
Option Explicit

Sub sort_union()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim iCt As Integer
    Dim maxCt As Integer
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("RangeSort").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Worksheets.Add.Name = "RangeSort"
    
    Set myRange = Union(Range("$E$12"), Range("$B$11:$C$12"), _
        Range("$G$14"), Range("$F$2"), Range("$F9"))
    
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "ORIGINAL:"
    Debug.Print myRange.Address
    
    iCt = 1
    Range("A1") = "Address"
    Range("B1") = "Row"
    Range("C1") = "Column"
    
    For Each myCell In myRange
        Range("A1").Offset(iCt, 0) = myCell.Address
        Range("B1").Offset(iCt, 0) = myCell.Row
        Range("C1").Offset(iCt, 0) = myCell.Column
        iCt = iCt + 1
    Next myCell
    maxCt = iCt - 1
    
    Call SortCurrentRegion
    
    Set myRange = Range(Range("A2").Value)
    'Debug.Print iCt; myRange.Address
    'create sorted union
    For iCt = 2 To maxCt
        Set myRange = Union(myRange, Range(Range("A1").Offset(iCt, 0)))
        Debug.Print iCt; myRange.Address
    Next iCt
    
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "SORTED:"
    Debug.Print myRange.Address


    'Delete Sheet "RangeSort"
    'On Error Resume Next
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Sheets("RangeSort").Delete
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub


Sub SortCurrentRegion()
    Dim sortRange As Range
    Set sortRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        
        'sort "Col B" = "Row" ascending
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    
        'sort "Col C" = "Column" descending
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    
        .SetRange Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Here the output of the Immediate Window:

```
ORIGINAL:
$E$12,$B$11:$C$12,$G$14,$F$2,$F$9

SORTED:
$F$2,$F$9,$E$12,$B$11:$C$12,$G$14
```

**Why is $E$12 in front of $B$11:$C$12?**
In the output of the Immediate Window we see that by adding address $C$11 to the union the range $B$11:$C$12 changes to the end of the union! ;-(

```
ORIGINAL:
$E$12,$B$11:$C$12,$G$14,$F$2,$F$9

 2 $F$2,$F$9
 3 $F$2,$F$9,$C$11
 4 $F$2,$F$9,$B$11:$C$11
 5 $F$2,$F$9,$B$11:$C$11,$E$12
 6 $F$2,$F$9,$B$11:$C$11,$E$12,$C$12
 7 $F$2,$F$9,$E$12,$B$11:$C$12            
 ^^-- $C$11 is added to the union here
 8 $F$2,$F$9,$E$12,$B$11:$C$12,$G$14
 ^^-- $B$11:$C$12 moved to the end of the union automatically

SORTED:
$F$2,$F$9,$E$12,$B$11:$C$12,$G$14
```