# Sorting comma-delimited string alphabetically in a smart way

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a string that looks like

`"Carol, Ernie, Alice, Bob, Dave"`

I want to pass it to a VBA function that sorts it so it becomes

`"Alice, Bob, Carol, Dave, Ernie"`

Is there a smart way to do this with built in functions that doesn't require a lot of custom code or am I out of luck?

Comment: use split then load that array into an [arraylist](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/) sort it and then use join to put it back or loop the array list to concatenate it back.

Comment: I was afraid of that, out of luck I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the idea at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45379461/2193968

This should work:

```
Function SortCSV(Value As String)
    Set Arr = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For Each Item In Split(Value, ",")
        Arr.Add Trim(Item)
    Next
    Arr.Sort
    SortCSV = Join(Arr.ToArray, ",")
    Set Arr = Nothing
End Function
```