# Sorting rows of string data in vba

Tags: vba

I'd like to sort delimited data rows on the fly using VBA. Here is the data that I have:

```
PM-10663 ::: AK:::1:::Jupiter_PI6-1:::Relinquishment request cancled time out 
PM-10721 ::: AK:::3:::Jupiter_PI6-2:::Automate SAS Simulator configuration - Prepare Dummy test files
PM-76960 ::: EA:::3:::Jupiter_PI6-1:::Handle Heartbeat Expire timer (interval) Received in Grant/Heartbeat Response
PM-99200 ::: EA:::3:::Jupiter_PI6-1:::Scheduled Job Support First HeartBeat - Transmit Expiry
PM-10684 ::: EA:::1:::Jupiter_PI6-2:::Update Swagger for Rest API to FE
PM-10822 ::: EA:::1:::Jupiter_PI6-2:::Add Code Owners
PM-10807 ::: EA:::2:::Jupiter_PI6-2:::Enabling SAS Cleaning Data 
PM-10327 ::: EA:::1:::Jupiter_PI6-2:::Add Coverage.out file to Domain-proxy repo to access to jenkins workspace
PM-73860 ::: KO:::3:::Jupiter_PI6-1:::Algorithm to obtain grant requests for RUs within same bandwidth - Part 2
PM-10472 ::: KO:::2:::Jupiter_PI6-1:::updating the api-spec go version
PM-99370 ::: KO:::3:::Jupiter_PI6-1:::Build Swagger for Rest API to FE
PM-10132 ::: KO:::5:::Jupiter_PI6-1:::Configure the SAS Simulator to test SAS errors
PM-10029 ::: KO:::2:::Jupiter_PI6-2:::Consider moving to Orchestration NATS bus to facilitate the Authentication and Authorization
PM-97240 ::: OM:::1:::Jupiter_PI6-1:::Define nats subject/schema definition for publish/subscribing CBSD_info_update message
PM-98250 ::: OM:::1:::Jupiter_PI6-1:::Procure the NB swagger/gRPC specification of retrieving CBSD_info_update from CBRS
PM-99420 ::: OM:::1:::Jupiter_PI6-1:::Configure the structure API client for DP
PM-10661 ::: OM:::3:::Jupiter_PI6-2:::Relinquishment failed.
PM-10662 ::: OM:::1:::Jupiter_PI6-2:::Relinquishment request canceled time out 
PM-77000 ::: OM:::3:::Jupiter_PI6-2:::Create Transmit Expiry Timer in Heartbeat Response
PM-93300 ::: OM:::3:::Jupiter_PI6-2:::Handle Grant Expire Timer Received in Grant Response - Part 2 
PM-98440 ::: OM:::3:::Jupiter_PI6-2:::Expose a Rest API to FE to provide SAS Default URL
PM-10217 ::: OM:::3:::Jupiter_PI6-1:::Hardcode the flow of DP - SAS communication
```

I want to first group by the second element (e.g., AK, EA, KO etc.,) and then group by the fourth element (e.g., Jupiter_PI6-x) and finally sort the data by the first element (PM-xxxxx).

This is how the data looks like right now:
[image]

And this is how I want the outcome to be:
[image]

I cannot use Excel sort because it means that I need to save, read, and write the data in a separate worksheet using sorting algorithms. I am getting this data via an API call into a VBA dictionary object. So, I need to use arrays or something to separate out the data. I have very limited knowledge about data arrays, let alone multiple arrays. I'd be very thankful if someone could help me with this.

Comment: So are we to assume that each Value in the Dictionary is one of the lines, above, and each line is a String (with the individual elements always delimited by the 3 colons)? The first delimiter is surrounded by space characters ... are these to be ignored/removed (before the sort)? What is in the Keys in the Dictionary?

Comment: "I need to save, read, and write the data in a separate worksheet using sorting algorithms" - no you don't. You can use a temporary worksheet to split the data out, re-order it and concatenate it back together again. Then just throw that worksheet away.

Answer (score 2):

There is no build-in sort to a Dictionary. Easiest way is to use an `AdoDB.RecordSet` for that.

Basically, create a Recordset with 5 fields, the first for the key of the dictionary, the other 4 fields contains pieces of your long string. Loop over your dictionary and add 1 records per entry. You can easily split this long string into pieces (I call them "tokens") with the `Split` function.

Now all you have to do is to issue the `Sort`-command and loop over the Recordset. Use the key-field to access the original entry of the Dict:

```
Sub SortMyDict(d as Dictionary)
    ' Create a Recordset with 5 string fields
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Fields.Append "key", adChar, 100
    rs.Fields.Append "f1", adChar, 100
    rs.Fields.Append "f2", adChar, 100
    rs.Fields.Append "f3", adChar, 100
    rs.Fields.Append "f4", adChar, 100
    rs.Open
    
    ' Loop over the dictionary to fill Recordset
    Dim key
    For Each key In d
        Dim tokens() As String
        tokens = Split(d(key), ":::")
        
        rs.AddNew Array("key", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"), Array(CStr(key), tokens(0), tokens(1), tokens(2), tokens(3))
    Next
    ' Sort
    rs.Sort = "f2, f4, f1"
    ' Loop over sorted recordset.
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        key = Trim(rs("key"))
        Debug.Print d(key)   ' Make up your mind what you want to do here.
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

End Sub
```

Note that I always advocate for early binding, so you need to add references to the `Scripting.Runtime` and `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects`.

Comment: Nice.  I had forgotten about `rs.Sort`.

Answer (score 0):

This works but may need tweaking to fit your data

```
Sub SplitAndSort()

    Dim arr1 As Variant
    arr1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value
    
    Dim lvar As Long, v As Variant
    For lvar = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        v = Split(arr1(lvar, 1), ":::")
        'Add the sort criteria to the start of the string. Separate with !!!
        arr1(lvar, 1) = v(1) & v(3) & "!!!" & arr1(lvar, 1)
    Next
    
    'See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function
    QuickSort arr1, LBound(arr1), UBound(arr1)

    'Remove the stuff we added
    For lvar = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        v = Split(arr1(lvar, 1), "!!!")
        arr1(lvar, 1) = v(1)
        Debug.Print v(1)
    Next

End Sub
```

I adapted the QuickSort at [VBA array sort function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function) - my variant array ends up with an extra dimension so I just added `,1` everywhere it referred to `vArray`